# Appropriate action when reviewing edits for unsalvageable or poor quality questions

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits

I recently got to the point where I have enough reputation to review suggested edits.

A common theme that I'm seeing in many of the suggested edits, is that they are (partially) fixing the spelling and grammar of what questions I would consider to be *poor quality* or *unsalvageable*.

What is the appropriate action in cases where the edits are partially fixing the spelling or grammar, but not actually improving the quality of the question?

I don't want to approve an edit that's incomplete, but there's no appropriate *rejection* category either, and I don't feel its worth my time improving an edit on low quality questions.

Comment: The advice in this Q&A is no longer valid. Please see ["Meta Stack Exchange Review queue workflows - Final release"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/269301) for a more up-to-date approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The first rule of editing is](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/#substantial-improvement):

1. **If you are going to edit a post, make sure you’re substantively improving it.**

Relatively minor spelling, grammar or formatting changes are fine, *if they result in **something** of lasting value to the site*. If they amount to [polishing a turd](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2lrkhj), then they're a waste of time and effort - the editor's, and now yours.

If the post being edited would still require substantial amounts of work to be acceptable on the site, then reject the edit with the **too minor** reason:

[image: Suggested Edit rejection reason: No Improvement - This edit does not improve the quality of the post.]

Comment: I agree with what you've said, but i don't feel the "too minor" reason encapsulates that: the edits are often substantive, and not minor, just incomplete and "polishing a turd".  Is there a way to add comments to an edit rejection, to clarify that?

Comment: Yes - select "custom" and type in whatever you feel best describes the problem.

Comment: Works best if your average wpm is over 130.