# Review queue workflows - Final release

Tags: discussion, review, announcements

All good things must come to an end and so must the [review queues project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351117/plans-for-updates-to-review-queues). This project would not have been successful without the community. Thank you all for the hours of reviewing, testing, and sharing your feedback along the way. With that said, this will be our final major release. In this post, I’ll summarize the changes we’ve made to the overall queue workflows and the specific adjustments to the Reopen votes queue.

### Changes to the First posts queue

**First posts → First questions AND First answers queue**

- To avoid context switching, and recognizing that asking and answering require slightly different skill sets, we are creating two separate queues to handle the individual post types.
- The purpose of these queues remains the same – helping new users learn how to use the site. With that in mind, reviewers will be able to choose from three actions: Looks OK, Edit, and Share feedback.
- It can take time to develop the skills to write a good question or answer. A user’s first few posts may require extra attention and to help new users get the hang of things, First questions and First answers will accept **up to three posts per user** if their first couple aren’t successful.
- Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the *Community* account.

[image: Canned feedback options appears in modal]
[image: Canned feedback appears as a comment from Community]

### Changes to the Reopen votes queues

1. **“Significant edit” option**

   [image: Post edit screen with significant edit option]

   - This feature appears when editing a closed question and allows editors to indicate if they’re making a minor edit (i.e. grammar, spelling) or a significant edit. By submitting an edit for review, the editor agrees that their edit attempts to resolve the question’s close reason(s) and should be considered for reopening in the Reopen votes queue.
   - Once a significant edit has been submitted, editors are still able to return to the edit screen and make further adjustments. Significant edit status will also be indicated in both revision history and post timeline pages.

   [image: Post edit screen with significant edit submitted]
2. **Significant edits in the Suggested edits queue**

   - Users who do not have enough reputation to submit an edit outright will have their significant edits go into the Suggested edits queue accompanied by a post notice.

   [image: Significant edit in Suggested edits queue post notice]

   - Actions in the Suggested edits queue will change based on whether the edit has been flagged as a Significant edit. In the case of a Significant edit, reviewers will be able to Approve and reopen or Approve and leave closed.
   - It takes two approve votes (any combination of Approve and reopen or Approve and leave closed) to remove the task out of the Suggested Edits queue. If at least one of the votes is Approve and reopen, a new task will be created in the Reopen votes queue.
3. **Leave closed reasons**

   - If a Reopen votes reviewer elects to leave a question closed, the reviewer will be presented with a “Leave closed reason” modal (similar to the close reason modal) that will return feedback to the editors. For example, if a question was originally closed because it lacked details, it may still require further details even after an edit, or new issues with the question might present themselves like asking too many questions at once.

   [image: Reasons to leave a question closed appear in modal]

   - In addition to inbox notifications, the closed question’s post notice will also be updated with more information.

   [image: Post notice updated with new close reason]
4. **Multiple opportunities to send question for review**

   - We’ll be launching this feature without any limits – users will be able to submit multiple edits on individual posts. We’ll take a look at the data in a few weeks to see if any abuse of the feature has occurred and take mitigation steps as needed.
   - [Stack Overflow only] Reviewers will not see posts that

     1. they’ve voted to reopen since last closed, and
     2. voted to close since the post was last edited.

     Moderators are exempt from this restriction.
5. **Bug fix:** “Don't cause the reopen vote of the user, whose edit pushed the closed question into the reopen queue, to invalidate the review”

   This bug fix is also included as part of this release. You can read Kyle’s detailed response [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410755/10886640).

### Other changes to the Review queues

1. **Turn off the  Help & improvement queue**

   - H&I has been our least productive queue. Over the last 90 days, only 9 tasks went into the queue each day on average, compared with 2,215 for First Posts (our busiest queue) and 188 for Reopen Votes (our second-to-last busiest). Consequently, this queue will be turned off. It will remain in the listing until its current items are exhausted, and will then be removed. History for and badges awarded from this queue will remain as they are.
   - With the addition of the First questions queue, we expect that questions with potential can get the same assistance they need more quickly.
   - Questions that would have ended up in this queue from Triage (with a Needs community edit action) will now enter the First questions queue.
2. **New actions for Late answers queue**

   The Late answers queue has been successful in identifying and removing low quality posts, repeat answers, and spam. Reviewers were able to take any number of actions on a task, so the objective of this queue wasn’t all that obvious. To clear up any ambiguity and focus on identifying problematic answers, we’ve defined three actions: Looks OK, Edit, and Delete.
3. **Keep Triage queue (Stack Overflow only)**

   - Triage will continue to handle questions only.
   - Triage will be available on all sites, but only turned on by default on Stack Overflow. Have a meta discussion and ask a moderator to [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) if your site wishes to add the Triage queue.
4. **Name change: Low quality posts →  Low quality answers (Stack Overflow only)**

   This queue will continue to handle answers only.
5. **Misc.**
   We won't issue new Reviewer or Steward badges for the queues that were turned off, but this won’t have any effect on badges already earned in these respective queues.

   Along with all these changes, here is an updated visual of the Review queues map –

   [image: Flowchart of review queues]

### What about issue X, Y, Z?

As mentioned earlier, this is our final major release. We will not be pursuing the proposed suggested tasks feature at this time. We didn't feel that it was going to significantly increase curation activities on the site and therefore didn't warrant the high development cost.

There are still a few outstanding issues related to suggested edits that have proved to be technically challenging. We’ll respond in those original Meta request posts as soon as we decide on a course of action.

### Feedback

Please leave your feedback and any bugs you may discover related to this release below this post. We will be monitoring this post until Friday, September 10th. Report any further issues after September 10th as new questions on Meta.

Comment: *"appear as a comment from the Community account."* - Neat!

Comment: "Significant edits in the Suggested edits queue".. is that in the Suggested Edits queue or the Reopen Votes queue? What is the URL of those tasks? Will one come across them when reviewing Suggested Edits?

Comment: Will the notice in the review dropdowns disappear after some specific time? I notice it is not going away when I click it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJGw.png

Comment: This might be a good spot to advertise [Generic Review Tool](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/generic-review-tool.user.js), which automatically looks for and opens new review tasks in a separate tab (it's a lighter weight alternative to Review Stalker Reloaded, basically).

Comment: "Looks OK, Edit, and Delete" for Late Answers. Does that mean 500 reputation point users now effectively have Delete privileges? Or does that send the post to another queue?

Comment: @Xnero You're posting a lot of comments that are already mentioned in answers or that should be answers - please don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: @Unconsidered I think it would be "Recommend deletion" but it would be good to have CM input.

Comment: As a side note, in SOpt lots of new messages are in English. I know there's a "solution" to this (go [here](https://pt.traducir.win/) and translate), but honestly, I'm getting tired of this "SE changes site -> messages are in English -> community translates" cycle. I'd love to see a better solution, that doesn't require the community acting **after** the change is made.

Comment: Too bad this is featured roght now. I'd rather see Aaron's post about removing the top bar preferences featured :(

Comment: [Any timeline on the review UI suspension improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356377/new-review-suspensions-mod-ux)

Comment: @Ramhound The review UI suspension improvements have already been released and available to moderators. Is there a specific feature you'd like to see?

Comment: @Unconsidered TheSimplifire is correct. The action will appear as "Recommend deletion" or "Delete" based on the user's privileges.

Comment: @LisaPark I hope that it sends the post to the Low Quality Post queue then, because I'm not seeing how new reviewers have enough experience with site rules to have delete privileges. There are already actual Answers getting deleted in the Low Quality Posts queue, due to confusing with the rules.

Comment: Late Answers requires a downvote before being about to select delete. I love wasting my rep on DVs. I'm sure everyone wants to waste 20/40 rep going through the queue each day. Absurd.

Comment: @LisaPark - Yes; I submitted an answer to that question, was given feedback that would be attempted to consider it, was just wondering if that was still on the table.

Comment: Just wondering... *why* was the design changed in the first place? Did reviewing users complain about the earlier format? I'm sure the earlier format was much better atleast on Chemistry.SE

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney If the post is deleted, you get your rep back, and IIRC you need a post to have a negative score to delete.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek posts with 0 score can receive delete and recommend deletion votes (at least in the old queue... I'm not clear yet on exactly how the new one works, but I am 100% on board with encouraging people to downvote when voting to delete. One should always be readier to downvote than to delete!)

Comment: I really think you should reconsider the canned comment. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68947580/down-voting-questions-for-no-reason-is-not-good) of it being used where it makes no sense at all. It just adds to the confusion.

Comment: @Unconsidered - Screenshots are appreciated when providing screenshots, for the rest of the classes, your example question has already been deleted

Comment: This change is a *huge huge step backwards.  I will not coddle new users when there is reason to downvote and/or close.  Give us back those options.  Surely SE/SO knows that "new accounts" is not equal to new users??

Comment: @TRC Users have been requesting improvements to reviewing for years. Some of the design changes were probably just seen by staff as an opportunity to freshen things up based on what they wanted, in addition to some opportunity to bring those pages in line with the Stacks design system.

Comment: @Zanna I have reservations about these kind of statements. I've seen more irresponsible drive-by voting than perhaps you'd imagine. Not just that, but also taunting users in the comments who haven't earned enough rep to downvote back. It only takes 1 high-rep user to throw a low rep into the question ban.

Comment: @TylerH - Thanks for the info. I respect the fact that the new design can be useful on other sites where I'm not active. I was trying to say that it'd have been better if the old response options weren't completely removed - they could have been kept along with the new design.

Comment: @bad_coder What do you mean? I said one should be more willing to downvote *than to delete*.  If one thinks a post should be removed from the site altogether, one should surely be willing to downvote it. Would it be less bad if instead of casually downvoting, people casually delete-voted?

Comment: @LisaPark Please mark [this canonical wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/348196) as accepted to help users quickly find existing bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: @Zanna I mean your comment goes along the [classic lines of Shog9 here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351971). But I wouldn't downvote a well formed question in an area I have expertise in if I deem the OP couldn't -even with reasonable effort- find the duplicate or formulate the problem more accurately. I close a lot of questions without downvoting and prefer they roomba with score zero. That way it counts less against the OP's [positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234963) nor [penalizes the OP's earned rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124799).

Comment: @bad_coder You should be voting on the content, not on the person. If you are voting or not voting based on whether you worry OP will have a tough time, that's not how voting is designed to work.

Comment: @TylerH why should I not factor in posters? My previous examples are valid although they only scratch the surface. I see your objection -which sounds like an absolute- being necessarily limited and partial. A kind of horse blinders argument perhaps in Tim Post's words: *"users inventing rules"*. (In any case this isn't the thread to have this discussion so I disengage here. I don't think the way you invoke the pretense rule -as overly simplistic- applies to the cases I showed.)

Comment: @bad_coder thanks - I see your point. I think post bans are handed out too easily. Anyway, what I really want to see is not so much more downvotes as fewer flags for deletion on posts that shouldn't be deleted at all.

Comment: Did you even test this on non-tech sites? Why does it post comments about code on humanities sites???

Comment: @curiousdannii That's hardly the only such wording blunder. Here's another: apparently now all answers must be "solutions".

Comment: @bad_coder because votes are for content, not for people. That's been the case since the beginning of the site. You should vote how you would if the content were posted automatically by the system itself via an AI. If *who* posted the content is the reason for your vote... that's misusing the vote button.

Comment: I initially upvoted this because there are some good things here, but I've changed it to a downvote after working in the new First Q&A queues. The number of options in these queues is severely limited -- I keep having to perform actual moderation (like vote to close) and then click "Looks OK" to finish the review for a post that is clearly not OK. I understand that there will be some bugs at first, but the workflow seems like it was designed by people who don't have much (if any) experience actually reviewing first posts -- many of which are not OK and/or need more than an edit or "feedback".

Comment: You know, if you guys want, there's a significant number of us here who would be happy to beta test this stuff out and give you some real user/curator feedback before you 'Final release' it out onto the entire broad spectrum of sites like this.

Comment: This is not a question! It is a answer. Why is this posted as an question?

Comment: @TobyHarnish, Meta sites aren't just for questions. They are also for announcements, regular updates, and site discussions.

Comment: I find the new options very limited. And for few questions, I would like to **Edit** the questions and also **Share Feedback**, but as soon as I hit **Save Edit**, I get re-directed to the next question/answer.

Comment: If I were to describe the new process in one word: Frustrating.

Comment: @Gangula - I quite agree, this "forced funnelling" of reviewers into dialog tunnels is poor UI/UX design. The old natural freeform method of reviewing was much better.

Comment: @LisaPark I don't understand what *"proposed suggested tasks feature"* means?

Comment: @LisaPark About `Name change: Low quality posts → Low quality answers (Stack Overflow only)`: Doesn't this apply to other stackoverflow sites like pt.stackoverflow.com? If the answer is **"no"**, it seems that this has been causing a problem in the translations of the stackoverflow "cousin" sites (eg:.: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/351091), in the title it is always shown as `resposta` ("anwser" in Portuguese), even when it comes to questions.... If the answer is "yes" (name change will be applied on **"cousins"** sites) when will it be done?

Comment: This is a better approach, indeed. More accurate.

Comment: I got 2 downvotes right after posting my answer on stackoverflow, which brings me -4 (!) to reputation. And I can't see any way to know WHY it was downvoted... 
Great feature! It definitely motivate people to share their experience and help others!

Comment: @LisaPark I just updated this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844) of the FAQ post about how duplicates work, so it describes that, for the post to go to the Reopen Queue, there's now a "Submit for review" checkbox to check if the changes are a "significant edit". This question here says you're "... launching this feature without any limits ....", where I assume this just means the number of times edits can cause the post to go to the review queue, not the 70 days edit time limit. I also added a link to here for more info. If either of these is incorrect, please edit that answer.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

### Complete list of reported feature requests and bugs<sup>1</sup>

| Type | Excerpt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Missing 'Flag', 'Close', and 'Share' buttons in First Questions/Answers](/a/369017) - Dup: [1](/a/369027), [2](/a/369251) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Missing 'Skip' button in the First Answers queue](/a/369021) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [New actions for Late Answers queue not deployed](/a/369026) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Typo in Help Center article for First Answers queue](/a/369032) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Blank text for "not enough reputation" message](/a/369035) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Blank text for "reached daily limit" message on First Answers](/a/369040) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The indicator for First Questions and First Answers is never red](/a/369127) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Missing space between OP and OP's reputation](/a/369214) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The "Staff" label is not aligned with the user detail in the queues](/a/369095) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Comments cannot be deleted by moderators](/a/369111) - Dup: [1](/a/369158) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [No way to correctly handle non-answers in First answers](/a/369036) - Dup: [1](/a/369039), [2](/a/369063), [3](/a/369135) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The "Learn more" button doesn't work on Stats and History tabs](/a/369038) Dup: [1](/a/369053) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Make the "Share feedback" and "Leave closed" modals movable](/a/369049) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answers reviewed in First Answers reappear in Late Answers](/a/369058) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The "Delete" button doesn't work properly in "Late Answers"](/a/369084) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The "edit" option is missing in "First answers" queue](/a/369045) - Dup: [1](/a/369116), [2](/a/369150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Generic error message when submitting empty feedback](/a/369119) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Comments cannot be flagged by users](/a/369111) - Dup: [1](/a/369158), [2](/a/369430) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Blank text for "reached daily limit" message on Reviews page](/a/369108) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Review progress exceeds the upper bound](/a/369191) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Selecting "Other Action" in First Questions or First Answers does not clear the post from the queue](/a/369545) - Dup: [1](/a/369714) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Low opacity in First Questions/Answers queues when logged out](/a/369059) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Canned comments on international sites are in English](/a/369047) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Triage blocks questions from getting to close queue for about a day](/a/369072) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Feedback from First Questions and First Answers is not really anonymous](/a/369073) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Pending edit suggestions are not visible in First Answers queue](/a/369092) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Custom flags raised in review audits are real](/a/369109) | [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Casting a close vote refreshes the page in First Questions queue](/a/369117) - Dup: [1](/a/369490) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Inconsistent font size in the reopen review box](/a/369183) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Code-related comments on non-code-related sites](/a/369111) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Capitalization issues in Help Center article for LQP queue](/a/369102) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Canned comments are too specific to Stack Overflow](/a/369158) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Manual flags fail bad-post audits in Triage](/a/369241) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Question age in review is reported differently to on the question](/a/369512) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Inline edit takes you out of First questions and into Suggested edits queue](/a/369532) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [First Answers Canned Responses Give Help Link to "How to Ask"](/a/369680) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Selecting "Share feedback" completes audits too easily](/a/369138) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Users aren't returned to the review page after editing if editor opens in new page](/a/369322) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answer went through First Answers queue twice](/a/369358) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ["Please log in to review" banner is blank for logged out users](/a/369393) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Posting and deleting a comment allows you to complete the review](/a/369529) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ["Other action" should be "Other actions" (plural)](/a/369559) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Weird word wrapping in queue descriptions in some non-English sites](/a/369610) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Empty queues show no message on their respective review page](/a/369614) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Identical comments from LQP and LA queues are not merged together](/a/369618) - Dup: [1](/a/369671) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Typo in FQ Help Center page references answers instead of questions](/a/369694) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ["Flag" and "Edit" links are missing from posts on completed/ inactive review pages](/a/369894) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The URL for the Stats or History for a review queue changes to a review task URL once the page is loaded](/a/370030) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Allow flagging posted canned/anonymous comments](/a/369067) - Dup: [1](/a/369158) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Bring back the "I'm done" button for First questions](/a/369037) - Dup: [1](/a/369143), [2](/a/369209) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make the canned feedback options configurable per site](/a/369018) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Do not abandon progress toward the First Posts Steward badge](/a/369016) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Mention that queues are retired in pop-ups and Help Center](/a/369041) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Update phrasing of LQP Help Center verbiage](/a/369043) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Move the First Posts queue to the bottom](/a/369019) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Rename the "Share feedback" option to "Share anonymous feedback"](/a/369044) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Update the pages that reference the now-retired first posts queue](/a/369048) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Update the Community♦ user profile to mention anonymous comments](/a/369068) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add "Share" button on the "Other answers" tab](/a/369136) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add an option to (easily) delete anonymous comments](/a/369050) - Dup: [1](/a/369080) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Don't show Community's comments in the Moderator dashboard](/a/369060) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Disable replies to the community user](/a/369062) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make failing audits only possible at final stage](/a/369121) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Don't notify the user who posted the anonymous comment](/a/369140) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Change the wording of the "Submit for review" button](/a/369137) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove edit link in Late Answers](/a/369208) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add OP shading to the revisions summary in the Reopen queue](/a/369210) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Let site moderators customize comment text wording available on their site](/a/369111) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Change the "Submit" button to "Continue" when the action not final](/a/369122) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Clarify closure notice text about edits made to the post](/a/369130) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Disable the "Edit" option for low-rep users when suggesting an edit is not possible](/a/369161) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Custom anonymous comments](/a/369182) - Dup: [1](/a/369258) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Change wording of the significant edit checkbox](/a/369028) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Non-bumping edits](/a/369024) | [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add "Ignored tags" filter to the queues](/a/369042) - Dup: [1](/a/369020) | [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Have a default, auto-checked "Keep closed" reason](/a/369023) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove the "Share feedback" option from the First Questions queue](/a/369034) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Send questions flagged as low-quality to the Close Votes queue directly](/a/369146) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Suggestions for additional canned comments](/a/369154) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove the "How do I use the First posts queue?" link from the Help Center](/a/369170) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Replace the "Community" bot for the canned comments with a new "Review" bot](/a/369231) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Increase close and reopen vote weight for tag badge holders](/a/369247) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Link-only canned response](/a/369392) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Display site-specific close reasons in the Reopen queue](/a/369362) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add "question isn't in the right language" canned comment on non-English sites' FQ queue](/a/369363) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add "from review" link to canned comments](/a/369389) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add "close"/ "flag" link to *question* in FA queue](/a/369402) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add link to main Review Queue dashboard/ all queues to individual queue pages](/a/369565) - Dup: [1](/a/369639) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add "flag" option to LQP queue](/a/369617) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add comment, flag, and edit (w/o reopen) options to Reopen Votes Queue](/a/369620) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [Let sites decide whether or not they are a "code-related"](/a/369142) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [What's the plan for hiding retired queues?](/a/369194) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [What is the reason for having comments be from Community?](/a/369126) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [Will the badge stats for the Help & improvement queue be gone?](/a/369128) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [Why does the "Recommend deletion" button show a dialog similar to the flag dialog?](/a/369252) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [How to deal with answers to off-topic questions in First Answers](/a/369357) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [How does the significant edit checkbox work with the existing reopen criteria?](/a/369493) |  |

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Idea stolen from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/8967612).</sub>

Comment: Maintaining the list referenced in the footnotes was a serious pain :P

Comment: This is sheer beauty :) Was it manually compiled or with at least some automation involved? As I see value in making this a script/bot for this if such community wikis are to be officially endorsed. It saves up a lot of times scrolling/bookmarking/remembering who reported what.

Comment: @Oleg It was (unfortunately) manually compiled. It's currently quite difficult to automate (and cumbersome to do manually) because not all answers follow the same format (e.g., tagging, heading, etc.) but I wrote a suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369149/348196) for the company to implement templates for answers to announcements/product-discovery/... posts and to automatically generate an index based on that. Hopefully, it'll be conidered.

Comment: @41686d6564 oh, that's a pity (but non-impossible to do, come to think of it - I might give it a shot later this week [but it obviously will need some cooperation from reporters to include something like the headers you proposed for the automation to be able to scrape titles]). This is a very, very nice idea - those "product discovery" posts really stretch the capabilities of the Q&A model. Even templates as middle ground would be great given how well they work on sites like Stack Apps.

Comment: I wonder how many real reviewers were involved in beta testing these new review queues? I believe a lot of these bugs or missing features could have been caught in a proper testing case - especially those that are really obvious.

Comment: Can this be added to the list of bugs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369694/293308

Answer (score 116):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)/[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### No way to correctly handle non-answers in First answers

Right now, users are forced to flag the post and then pick "Looks OK".

Could the "First answers" feedback options include something along the lines of "This is not an answer" (such as link-only, "Me too," or "Thanks" answers)? It would allow us to give quick feedback on posts that should be flagged NAA without waiting for the Low Quality Answers queue to get to it—and potentially allow for the answer to be fixed without being deleted, in the case of link-only answers (which I often see fixed in response to comments).  Ideally, selecting this would also flag the post as NAA, or at least send it to the low-quality queue.

[image: Feedback dialog for new user answer with "Answer is unclear" and "Answer needs supporting information" options]

None of the current options really apply to non-answers.  I can flag the answer, but I'm unable to complete the review without saying that it "Looks OK" (when really it has serious issues).

Comment: ... I feel like the links to flag should still be on the post, which would allow you to flag it as NAA. Not sure why they're not there. The flag and close links also seem to be missing on questions. - Looks like it's supposed to be there but went AWOL - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369017/284336

Comment: @Catija Agreed that being able to flag as NAA somehow is definitely needed.  Maybe if this were added, selecting an NAA feedback option could automatically flag the post as NAA.  I think giving the user feedback about what constitutes NAA quickly is useful to help them fix the post, though, so having an option to both provide feedback and flag the post for further review seems ideal.

Comment: So doing any action just ends the review?

Comment: Personally, I liked the way the "Late Answers" queue *used* to work (and Lisa admits it was highly successful). I can see why some would like a fast-track-to-deletion, with "Delete" direct from First/Late Answers but I also feel that the two-tier system - flagging from Late/First Answers to send it into Low Quality Posts for deletion - actually provides a good 'safety mechanism'.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that very new reviewers (500 rep) should really be voting to delete answers. And those with very high rep (20k+) could, anyway, vote to delete as their review action in (the old) Late Answers queue. "Late Answers" wasn't broken, so why did they fix it?

Comment: Yeah, hard to see how any response in [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29669509) makes the slightest sense.

Comment: I also really miss a proper option here. When you have flagged a first answer that's not an answer, I would like to leave feedback, but the feedback you can give only have 2 options - not an option for "This is not really an answers". Maybe this 3rd option could be added to the "Share feedback" window.

Comment: We added flags back in, and we're going to be adding other options back in as well. I'm going to mark this as status-completed.

Comment: @kristinalustig I think flagging should be one of the actions to end the review... there's generally nothing else to do after that. That would help to deal with some of the problems in other answers here.

Comment: My suggestion for such kind of answers - downvote, leave a comment saying "not an answer" and click on Looks OK to complete the review. The "Looks OK" doesn't appear as Community user's feedback to the answerer, so it won't matter if you click on it just to complete the review. The answerer will anyway get your message through your comment and downvote. Same for questions where the template responses don't fit.

Comment: @TRC how can I spot robo reviewers though?

Comment: @Zanna What are robo reviewers? Aren't all reviews done by users themselves?

Comment: @TRC it's kind of a semi-formal name we give to those who review (usually approve, but the phenomenon is not limited to approvals) without thinking about what they are doing. The name is derived from such activity being overly "robotic"

Comment: people who click "No Action Needed" for every item and from now on will click "Looks OK"

Comment: @kristinalustig The flag issue is still there you still have to end up skipping as there is no good exit option

Comment: I have to say, I am pretty baffled that someone didn't think of NAA workflow and how you cannot complete review for such answers. This is pretty obvious stuff.

Comment: If this is status completed, why is [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191173/62294) the best we can do when reviewing a non answer in the First Answers queue?

Comment: @kristinalustig, This says status-completed, but a flag as a non-answer still doesn't complete the review or allow us end it with 'I'm Done'. Do I need to clear my browser cache or something?

Comment: @kristinalustig Perhaps you wanted to write [tag:status-pending], but the option wasn't available to you? Frustrating isn't it?

Comment: Do I select "Answer is unclear" or "Answer needs supporting information" if the answer is clearly spam? Sure, I _flagged_ it as spam (for someone else to delete), but I sure as heck can't select "Looks OK" after doing that.

Comment: Can the `status-completed` be removed from this as there is still ***No way to correctly handle non-answers in First answers***?

Comment: I've updated the status to planned - sorry for the confusion. We're working on this as we speak, as well as a bunch of other fixes, and we'll be sure to update y'all when we've gotten them out the door.

Comment: I actually find it pretty remarkable that this very obvious use case have been overlooked...

Comment: Until this is taken seriously, I'll continue to flag as "non-answer" and just click "Looks OK", as this is the option that makes most sense (although it doesn't really make any sense).

Comment: This applies to First Question queue as well.

Comment: You should now be able to flag answers as not an answer as normal, and then mark that you've finished your review using the "Other action" option.

Comment: I got suspended from review on DIY because of this.  See [What is the standard for determining a bad review (and subsequent suspension)?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/what-is-the-standard-for-determining-a-bad-review-and-subsequent-suspension)

Comment: I just handled a situation on U&L where a reviewer in the First Answer queue could-have should-have flagged an answer as NAA (it was a standard "me too" answer). I think that flagging is a non-obvious option while in the FA queue, and it'd be nice to make that more obvious or to add NAA options into the dialogue. @kristinalustig

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think that's a pretty good idea. I'm not actively working on Review Queues right now, but if you haven't already, could you submit that as a top-level post so that it can get community feedback / be appropriately triaged and handled as a request? Thanks!

Answer (score 107):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> Yaakov: This has been addressed, read [all of the details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369396/51).

#### Please do not abandon progress toward the First Posts Steward badge.

Noticing "First answers" and "First questions" were now separate, I checked "First posts":

[image]

Slowly but surely, I was working toward the Steward badge with the First Posts queue:

[image]

As this queue is now retired, progress towards this badge is no longer possible. Please do not abandon the progress toward this badge, progress that many users have worked *years* for.

Comment: It would be nice if they took the effort to split out your progress on this queue so that you had it applied to the two new queues created from it, but I don't know if that amount of work is feasible.

Comment: Badges you've already earned for First Posts will still be there but you won't be able to earn further badges as you won't be able to complete further reviews.

Comment: @kristinalustig I think what Thomas asked for was the transfer of counts onto the new system, since First Posts = First Questions + First Answers and nothing more.

Comment: @TylerH It is not. It is calculated by counting the number of tasks you've completed in the queue, so granting progress would require moving all the tasks between queues, which has the potential to break a lot of things since the queues are similar but functionally different.

Comment: @kristinalustig That doesn't really answer the question. I doubt anyone expected their badges earned in FP to be removed, but we are wondering if the literal years of progress and effort we put into the FP queue will be remembered with the changes, rather than just wiped clean

Comment: @animuson So change the criteria for badges related to First answer and First question queues such that they count tasks both in the queue itself and in the First posts queue. This should be much easier than moving tasks around in the database.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That would be literally more impossible of a task than moving things.

Comment: While not 'ideal', what about just dividing the First Posts progress by 2 (round down) and then adding that amount of progress to both First Answers and First Questions? So that 451/1000 would turn into 225/1000 and 225/1000.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I happen to be familiar with how the badge award scripts work and know that it is not anywhere nearly as simple as you think it is. Nor do I think there is much value in people continuing to try to think up ways that it "might be easier" because it's really not. So I'll just leave it at not possible.

Comment: This was my recommendation, as the dev who worked on it. There are technical reasons why we can't carry over the first posts counts to count towards first questions/answers scores. That said, we'll be thinking about other potential approaches to this that could address the request.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Should I reword my answer as a proper feature request, something like "feature request: dont abandon progress toward steward", or is this fine as is?

Comment: Seconding what @YaakovEllis just said. We want to be fair. We'll give some thought to a solution and reply back to this post.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov best to reword as a feature request if you can

Comment: @YaakovEllis how about deciding on a fixed percentage (ratio between FQ and FA in the old queue) and arbitrarely populating a field with those numbers as progress towards the new badges?

Comment: @YaakovEllis *"we'll be thinking about other potential approaches to this that could address the request"*. While it's good to know that you might still do something about this, didn't it occur to staff that users might just be a little upset to have their work / time wiped out like this? Didn't anyone think 'Hmm, maybe we should respect the time and effort that people have invested before we split this review queue'? And what assurance do users have that staff won't do something else in the future which will negate users' time & effort, without any warning (as far as I can tell)?

Comment: @LarsBosteen yes, it did occur to us. Yes, we talked about this (and the different options) before launch. I made the call then that we would not initially be able to transfer progress from one queue to the other. The reaction here is making us go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @luuklag "arbitrarily populating a field" would require completely rewriting the badge logic for this badge. It is something to consider, but it is not trivial.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Is it really more complicated than introducing a new field for each user which contains a fixed value (of the progress achieved before the transition) and adding this to the end result of the existing calculation?

Comment: @zovits yes, it is

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thanks for "going back to the drawing board", that's good to hear.

Comment: @YaakovEllis What technical reasons are there? The same as for showing vote counts without 1000 reputation, "we don't have the code for this"? If I can look at a user's review history and manually count questions and answers, obviously, a program can do the same.

Comment: Why not just turn the First Posts queue into either the First Questions or First Answers queue, like what was done for Low Quanlity Answers? That way, the First Posts count will still be retained as one of the two new queues.

Comment: @thedefault. we can show vote counts for < 1000 rep, but it adds a lot of overhead to the system (expensive query), so need to be cautious how much we open it up. We can also solve it here - nothing is impossible, but there are always costs associated with greatly complicating code, some different edge cases that also have to be considered.

Comment: @VincentThacker that is another option - pretend that FIrst Posts never happened, transfer the entire history to First Questions/Answers (though the queue actions dont line up exactly, so need UI updates for that). That would mean though that some people who earned badges for First Posts would lose them if they split their reviews between First Q/A.

Comment: @YaakovEllis, You can make a one-time gesture of goodwill: give the "Steward" badge to all those who have managed to go more than half the way from "Reviewer" to "Steward" (more than 625 reviews). And similarly - for those who have passed more than half the way to the "Reviewer" (125 reviews). For those who were only at the beginning of the path, the loss of the rating is not so painful. But those who were close to the new sign are now experiencing great sadness and disappointment. It is your moral duty to help them.

Comment: @YaakovEllis To be clearer, what I meant is that you changed `Low Quality Posts` to `Low Quality Answers` without changing either the review count or review history. Why couldn't you also change `First Posts` to `First Answers` in exactly the same way, while creating a new `First Questions` queue? For example, if I had 800 reviews on `First Posts`, the outcome would be 800 for `First Answers` and 0 for `First Questions`. Are there technical differences behind the queues that make such a similar change impossible?

Comment: @YaakovEllis, I don't think badges are taken away ever. Has that changed?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky, That might be ok for larger sites with considerable participation in the review queues, but on the smaller sites where it can literally take years to get to Reviewer or Steward, that can be the same 'kick-in-the-teeth' if they were just a few away from that half-way mark. I think the only reasonable suggestion would be a one-time roll through the FP queue to just dole out the First Questions and First Answers accordingly. I'm not so sure I'm convinced that a one-time-runs script like that has to complicate the rest of the code as Yaakov Ellis says. But we can only assume so.

Comment: @ouflak no that has not changed

Comment: @YaakovEllis at least you recognize it is not impossible, just that it is impossible without making larger changes to the codebase.

Comment: @user253751 I never said that it was impossible. Read the other comments please. Will be posting shortly on proposed solution.

Comment: **[Proposed fix is detailed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir)**

Comment: **The fix is now live**. [See here for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir).

Answer (score 102):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Bring back the "I'm done" button for First questions**

I just looked at a post in the First questions queue which consisted of a large and unreadable screenshot of the code and some text asking a question about that code.

None of the canned comments really fitted for that post, an edit by me would be no improvement and it definitely doesn't look OK. So I *could* downvote and/or leave a "uncanned" comment, but I *could not* complete the review. So I'm asking for a means to complete the review just as the "I'm done" button was.

Comment: There needs to be an option to cast a close vote that would end the review. I am stuck on a similar problem.

Comment: There's no way to end a review properly in the First Answers queue. After flagging a post, and you don't want to leave a comment, the only choice is "Looks OK".. ?!?

Comment: Also for first answers.

Comment: Also, the template responses have probably left NO way for us to complete the reviews of questions considered homework questions - where the OP puts zero effort into the question, and directly posts the assignment expecting us to answer it for them (eg. Name these alkanes). Such questions are specially common on Chem.SE and Physics.SE. In that case - 'looks OK' doesn't work, editing (to show effort) should be done by the OP, not us - and for 'share feedback', neither is the question broad, nor unclear. There's no option to just downvote and comment - the review can't be completed. Do fix it.

Comment: yeah please fix this. We're going to end up with millions of useless canned comments because we're forced to do something after downvoting and flagging etc

Comment: Agreed that this is a good idea. I'm going to be working on adding this option back in. Might take a few days, but I'll mark this as status-planned. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @kristinalustig Can we also have that "I'm done" instead of just *one* action automatically completing the review. There *may* be occasions where more than one action (Edit and leave a custom comment, for example) would be appropriate. Or downvote and delete-vote (in First Answers, for the latter).

Comment: One possible implementation of this: taking actions like flagging the post or voting to close could change the "Looks OK" option into "I'm done".

Comment: FYI: A fix for this was deployed today. At least on Stack Overflow—and, presumably, other sites—there is now a new _Other Action_ button that remains grayed out until either a) the post is flagged or voted on, or b) a comment is added or upvoted. I've included details on this on [the corresponding Meta Stack Overflow thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411061/reintroduce-im-done-to-the-first-answers-review-queue/411067#411067).  Thank you, @kristinalustig.

Comment: You beat me to it, Jeremy! I got this out yesterday, you should be able to use the "Other action" button like you had used the "I'm done" action in the past.

Answer (score 89):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Entirely Wrong `"\l\a\n\g\u\a\g\e"`

The English Language & Usage site should not be telling people to post code examples, but [somehow it nonetheless is](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/573552/correct-verb-to-go-to-a-website-open-surf-navigate/573679#comment1429602_573679):

[image: screenshot of wrong comment on ELU]

We even have comments complaining about people’s “solutions”:

[image: screenshot of yet another bad comments]

This makes no sense given how rarely “solutions” is an appropriate description of an answer on non-coding sites.

### Yet Another Bug: *Indelible Comments*

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> - Mods can now delete all community comments
> - Any user who is able to flag can flag these comments as *no longer needed*

Every time some silly bit of text is chosen for these, a comment cascade spews forth from random users about how silly and inappropriate these messages about computer code are on a non-programming site, cluttering up the post's comments.

***Nobody*** can flag or delete these, not even moderators! Oh you have the buttons, but these are false-flag operations: they won’t let you do it despite the buttons inviting you to try.

That means we cannot even fix the problems these are creating for us. Sure, we can delete the spew cascade, but that does no good: we are not permitted to delete the offending comments that caused the problem in the first place. So soon enough the silly comments will be repeated.

It's an ugly site-maintenance issue, and those entrusted with site maintenance are for the first time ever forbidden from carrying out their appointed task of cleaning up comments that cause the site problems.

This is a *big* mess. Please fix it.

### Feature Request

The choice of text for many of these only works on coding sites. Which ones are allowed, and how their text should read, should be something that the site moderators can configure for their own sites.

Comment: We're getting this too. Citations from Koine Greek lexicons aren't code!

Comment: @curiousdannii Well it's all Greek to me...

Comment: As a band-aid while this situation is being resolved, moderators *can* edit these comments to something more appropriate.

Comment: Mods can now delete community user comments

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thank you very, very much! I really appreciate how this got fixed so quickly. I hope you guys don't get depressed from all the negative feedback you must receive anytime anything at all ever changes, no matter how insignificant. Thank you for your work.

Comment: @YaakovEllis  Yay, ordinary users can flag a community user's useless comment!

Comment: @YaakovEllis Seems like this now has a potentially exciting short-to-medium–term benefit that wouldn't have been otherwise possible without the new user-flaggability! That's right, I'm looking at the opportunity for a cool new number-crunching post-implementation assessment post coming to an MSE post near you in six to eight nominal time units, since per Mari-Lou's comment, you'll now be able measure how often those auto-comments get flagged across the various SE communities, and what sorts of flags they incur. Hope this helps.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Can [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179907/cannot-flag-comments-made-community-regarding-dead-urls) be tagged as completed given the fix here?

Answer (score 70):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Please bring the skip button back

[image]

Can the skip button be also added again? I am still yet to go in college and am not aware of most concepts. In those times I used to skip the review. But in the new update skip button is not present. So can you please add the Skip button here?

Comment: Side-note: the skip button is missing only for "first answers", not "first questions"

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad. It's getting added back in now, will be live soon!

Comment: Added back in - skip away!

Comment: @kristinalustig Thanks for adding the skip button. It is very helpful for someone like me who has rep but not knowledge of various topics.

Answer (score 65):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Please allow us to flag the canned comments, and I don't think the system knows when a post has been corrected.

[image]

Please allow users to flag the canned comments for *no longer needed* (NLN). We're smart enough to know when the post has been corrected, which brings me to my second point: Is the system really smart enough to know when a post has been corrected?

Comment: In case it's looking at voting score for example: we've had answers resolve all their flaggable issues but still be bad solutions (but valid answers).

Comment: I uh... share your skepticism? This particular part of the codebase seems pretty old so I'm doing some archaeological digging and asking around to figure out why we are making this claim here and what in particular it pertains to.

Comment: @kristinalustig Like if I am voting to delete an answer based on a lack of meaningful citations/support, I don't really see the system being able to reliably determine when the quality of citations and support has been improved, that's something reviewers have to determine. Anyway, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @kristinalustig This bug-feature adds noise, not signal, to any SE site it erupts on.  The value proposition to SE sites over 'the rest of the internet" is "more signal, less noise" - this particular addition is utterly at odds with that core value.  If SE wants people to get frustrated with the community mod function - which is a key element to SE sites running smoothly - this is a fine example of how to dis-incentivize **unpaid volunteers** from spending their time in that necessary function. I expect that you are in the fix it team, but management needs to hear this message.

Comment: I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69041293) as NAA, and left the canned comment. The answer has been improved. The flag has been marked helpful (so that part of the system seems to assume it's an improvement), but the canned comment is still there and still unflaggable. At the very least the helpful NAA flag should allow me to flag the comment I raised.

Comment: users can now flag Community authored comments as "no longer needed"

Answer (score 60):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The image with [canned reasons for the first questions queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCVgi.png) and the one showing a [canned reason on an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfJgZ.png) both show canned comments that are specific to code. I'm not sure if you're planning on only rolling these out to Stack Overflow or other code-specific sites for now, your post doesn't mention that, so I'm assuming you're planning on rolling out these networkwide (I can't check, but I see the new queues on e.g. IPS, there's nothing in them so I don't know if that means those same canned comments are there). 
<strike>In that case: *Don't show the code-specific feedback reasons in  first answers/questions queues on all sites please. There are plenty of sites around where these would be nonsensical to have.*</strike>
Kristina just confirmed in the comment section [that the code specific reasons shouldn't show up on non-code related sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369018?noredirect=1#comment1231189_369018).

So that only leaves me with the bonus point request: **Please give each site the option to add their own reasons to this dialog,** while we might not need more or less code, but there are other details that we might want to bring attention to. (On [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369018#comment1231232_369018), I've also turned that into a separate question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369052/369802))

Comment: +20 for the last sentence alone!

Comment: The code-specific options shouldn't be showing on any non-code-related site. If you're seeing that anywhere, please let us know!

Comment: @kristinalustig Thank you! That's good to know, I've edited the post accordingly :)

Comment: On the second request - if there are general things that might make sense to add to this dialog, then we would definitely revisit that, but the overhead required to allow sites to add their own reasons would be quite substantial. I recommend creating a feature request in a separate post for this particular request, as it's too large in scope for us to handle as a part of our post-launch fixes.

Comment: @kristinalustig Sure, [done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369052/369802)!

Comment: @kristinalustig We just got a code related comment on rpg.se: [Can a Black Dragon Hatchling be raised to be good? Or is it inherently evil?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/514243)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yeah, and? What, are you saying black dragons can't write code?! (Or maybe that only someone inherently evil can write code?)

Comment: @Sarov I can't say that I've ever met a black dragon that could write code. But I guess absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Comment: @kristinalustig I noticed the code-related comment is also there [on the answer on Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/61293/why-ymir-jaw-titan-and-galliard-jaw-titan-look-so-different/65486#comment76735_65486)

Comment: The option "answer needs supporting information" is worded in terms of code ("please provide working code or citations to the documentation"). This option appears on all sites, and removing it would leave the "First answers" queue with only one canned feedback option, which seems too little. That option should be reworded on non-code-related sites, or (much better) customizable by the site mods.

Comment: Also, the template responses have probably left NO way for us to complete the reviews of questions considered homework questions - where the OP puts zero effort into the question, and directly posts the assignment expecting us to answer it for them (eg. Name these alkanes). Such questions are specially common atleast on Chem.SE and Physics.SE. In that case - 'looks OK' doesn't work, editing (to show effort) should be done by the OP, not us - and for 'share feedback', neither is the question broad, nor unclear. There's no option to just downvote and comment - the review can't be completed.

Comment: @kristinalustig Letting you know, as requested: code-specific comments [are appearing on SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13469/31394).

Comment: @kristinalustig:  I think this may have been linked elsewhere, but [code-specific comments have appeared on Physics.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/confusing-message-from-new-review-queue)

Comment: @kristinalustig I don't know if you are still hunting for more, but looks like Arqade also has a code related canned comment https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhY98.png - should I leave an answer on this question for it?

Comment: Hey all - thanks for all your feedback. We're rewording the "Share feedback" answer options so that they don't specifically mention code. It's waiting for review, so should be pushed today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 57):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the First Answers and First Questions review queues, most post menu items are gone. Only the 'Follow' link is shown:

[image]

Flagging/voting to close is essential for these queues, and sharing may help too (I use it quite often to report a post to Smoke Detector.)

Comment: Good catch - I'm going in and updating that now, should be fixed within the next couple of hours.

Comment: This should work just fine now, let me know if there are any issues!

Comment: @kristinalustig Thanks for bringing this back, but even after I flagged I still can't complete the review.

Comment: I would say the guidance here would be to flag and then if sharing feedback isn't appropriate, just to skip and move on to the next answer.

Comment: @kristinalustig Any chance you accidentally added "flag" to Triage by mistake in the process? Because there seems to already be an option for that in this queue.

Comment: @Unconsidered there is a very substantial (approx 100%) chance that I did that! Talking with Lisa (designer) to figure out exactly which queues should have which post menu items. Might take me a day or two to get it all ironed out.

Comment: @kristinalustig "the guidance here would be to flag and then if sharing feedback isn't appropriate, just to skip and move on" -- why is that? Isn't flagging an answer or voting to close a question an action that reviews the post? They take the same amount of effort as any choosing any other option, so not counting them as a review seems odd, particularly when none of the other options may even be appropriate. The older version had an "I am done" button, which would be very useful here.

Comment: This has not been completely fixed.  The "Flag" button is there but the "Close" button is still missing in the First Questions review.

Comment: @kristinalustig thanks for the fix, but could you please have a look at Eric's comment? The 'close' link is still missing. I know I can access it via Flag as well, but it's one more click - that tends to add up after a while :)

Comment: Ideally put all the buttons back...

Comment: Hey all, thank you so much for all the feedback. Lisa and I spent a long time talking about this yesterday, and we determined that it makes the most sense to add in the entire post menu to the First Questions, First Answers, and Late Answers queues (except for the Edit button, because there's already an edit action). I'm going to be working on this and other fixes today and next week. We'll get these fixes in ASAP, thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'm not using those new queues because most times they're useless. If I vote, comment or flag, it doesn't count as an action. I can't vote to close. Edit is not an option when the question is not salvageable (why can't I close in those cases? Closing should be a valid option in FQ queue), and the canned comments are so generic that don't apply in most cases. I've tried to use them, but I gave up. For now, I'm doing everything outside the queues. I really hope SE reviews all of it

Comment: @kristinalustig Any update on when we will get vote to close back?

Comment: I'm planning on shipping it today, we're just having some build issues right now. I'll update y'all/all the relevant answers once I can actually get it pushed to production.

Comment: This fix is shipped and should be live for First Questions, First Answers, and Late Answers queues. Please let me know if you have any issues with the update!

Answer (score 54):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### Disable replies to the community user

Just saw an interaction with one of the canned community responses [out in the wild](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/52257/384030):

[image: New user attempting to respond to the Community user]

The Community user left a canned comment ("Please provide additional details [...]"), and the user responded by asking what they wanted more detail about.

This of course will notify no one. And the user's question is valid. Could there be a modal or link to the [community user description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) explaining to users what triggered this response?

Comment: That's part of the reason why I don't like using the Community ♦ user's name for this. Something like "Automated comment" would've been better. And hovering over / clicking on the "username" would explain what that is.

Comment: @41686d6564 something tells me users will gleefully keep replying to "Automated comment" as well :) I don't think anything short of a big red message explaining that this is an automated comment hat can't be replied to (while ensuring the comment cannot be added) will stop them.

Comment: @41686d6564 Or identify the Community user as a bot! That was [requested here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367945/152515), and declined but only due to being out of scope for the release. I've requested it here formally: [Please use the new Mod/Staff badge tech to identify Community as a bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369071/please-use-the-new-mod-staff-badge-feature-to-identify-community-as-a-bot)

Comment: @doppelgreener Identifying Community as a bot would make it more confusing: users could easily think their posts had been reviewed by the bot and it sent an automatic comment.

Comment: @Anonymous I've seen some of those comments on post and the relevance for the post is.. very disappointing. So perhaps the resemblance isn't really off.

Comment: @Anonymous Possibly, but the current situation is worse so that would still be an improvement.

Comment: I think you guys are missing the point: **a user _should_ be able to reply, but the _actual reviewer_ should be notified instead!** Or whom should a user be asking otherwise? There's about as much point in disabling reply as in replying itself...

Comment: We're not going to disable comments, but the bot tag and tooltip that Yaakov has added should mitigate this issue. I'm going to status-declined this for now and if our fix doesn't seem like it's working after a bit, please submit this as its own feature request.

Answer (score 46):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Exclude Community actions from popping up as "moderator actions" on the Moderator dashboard.

[image]

Comments from the Community user shows up as a moderator action on the dashboard. This is a bit of a distraction as every review now posts the comment as a Community user. Can we exclude the Community user's actions from showing up on the dash?

Comment: So basically, everyone gets to be a moderator now. Cool 

Comment: Related: [Don't send notifications to the person who posted the comment if they happen to be following the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369140/348196).

Comment: It's certainly wrong for comments **posted by a non-mod user** to be converted to comments with a mod diamond. What on earth was wrong with "User - from review" as before?

Comment: @AndrewLeach IMO, I think it's nice that those comments are added by the Community user. What's unfortunate though, is that the Community user is considered a mod.

Answer (score 42):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Add an option to (easily) delete anonymous comments

I suppose you keep track of which user posts the comment even though it's displayed under the Community ♦ user's name. If it's not feasible to add a <kbd>Delete</kbd> button visible only to the user who posted the comment, then maybe a single "No longer needed" flag (by them) should delete the comment instantly similar to what happens when flagging "thanks" comments and the like.

Comment: Adding a delete option would certainly be preferred. Having to flag one's own comment seems excessive.

Comment: @Unconsidered That's what I prefer too but I added that as a fallback in hopes that this doesn't get declined. Note that "No longer needed" flags don't affect your account in any way. Plus those comments are technically not under your name anyway.

Comment: I guess that depends on the perception of "don't affect your account in any way". I don't want to raise my flag-count. So I'm not inclined to flag anything, for any reason.

Comment: If they were going to track ownership/original author of the comment, then there's no need to add conditional flag weight code; just add said delete option.

Comment: Please let me (as a mod) delete these comments!

Comment: @Zanna Not even mods can clean them up?

Comment: Nope! I just get a notification saying the comment will be deleted automatically when the post gets fixed, but of course such comments can be wrongly posted. I think I'd rather not have these comments at all

Comment: @Zanna you (as a mod) can now delete these comments

Comment: @YaakovEllis hallelujah!!

Answer (score 39):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Since the Community♦ user is now posting comments on behalf of the review queue, this should be reflected in the profile description.

Especially given these will be posted on the posts on new users, that activity should be reflected in the profile to help against confusion. It could be as simple as a bullet (possibly on top of the list) which says:

> - Post comments on behalf of the review queues.

Answer (score 38):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### Rename the "Share feedback" option to "Share anonymous feedback" or add the word "anonymous" to its description

It's not immediately obvious that that option is used to provide *anonymous* feedback. It's only mentioned after one selects the option and then clicks <kbd>Submit</kbd> <sup>(and in a place where it's easily missed)</sup>. I think to encourage people to provide feedback, it should be highlighted that it will be anonymous.

I'd prefer something like this:

[image]

But if you need the option's title to be concise, then at least add it to the description:

[image]

Comment: Makes sense! I'll work on this change and it'll be out today or tomorrow.

Comment: @kristinalustig You might want to take [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369073/348196) into account while deciding on the wording.

Comment: Ah, good call. I'll need to think about this more and talk it over with the team to determine how to proceed. Still planning on doing something to fix this, so I'll leave it status-planned.

Comment: Why not have ***two*** options? One for *anonymous* feedback and one for regular. I don't really care having my name appear on the comment and this way OPs can ping you with further questions. As brought up in other answers here, users can't reply to the anonymous community comment and are left with more questions

Comment: As we're planning on having two options for feedback (both anonymous and non), I'm going to decline this particular suggested implementation of the fix.

Answer (score 36):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

### Feedback from First Questions and First Answers is not really anonymous

[image: Feedback not anonymous]

While certainly the ***vast majority*** of first posters will not know how to access the information, as can be seen in the `gif` above, it is trivial to identify who provided the "anonymous" feedback. Moreover, experienced users may also form opinions about users based on their feedback. Security though obscurity is not really security.

Perhaps there is an alternative wording that more clearly describes that the feedback is less immediately tied to you but doesn't call it "anonymous"?

Comment: If/when the "I'm done" button is [restored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037/348196), the review result could be changed to "Reviewed" (or whatever will be used for "I'm done") instead of "Share feedback". That way, it's not immediately obvious the exact action that the user selected. It could still be inferred if they're the only reviewer or by comparing the time of the comment to the time of the review.

Comment: FYI, I had requested highlighting the word "anonymous" and it got a [status-planned]. I just [pinged the staff member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1231379) about this so that they can hopefully take it into account.

Comment: What’s even the point of providing feedback, if it’s going to be that trivial, to determine who provided the feedback.  Might as well just submit it as the user themselves, add a sentence to whatever they typed (no matter what the length is), explaining the feedback was an commentary from the review queue. Revenge downvotes are a real problem especially on Stack Overflow.  Users will find any community, they have the ability to downvote contribute, that is shared between the reviewer on themselves

Comment: Perhaps "unattributed" might be a better word than anonymous.  Personally, I don't think it should be anonymous anyway - if a new user needs help understanding what's required, they should be able to ask.  Attributing comments to Community is as bad as sending emails from `noreply@example.org`....

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE:** I've noticed [SE is trying to fix some of these issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272/368934), but the fixes create problems of their own.  Since these have't been implemented yet, I've made a [separate answer on that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369717/368934) to address those issues.

---

> Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the *Community* account.

Sounds neat, but when you think about it:

### 1. It allows any user with 500 reputation to comment as official Stack Exchange

First of all, Community appears as a moderator.  A lot of users would delete their posts if a moderator didn't approve (can you honestly say that a moderator's comment doesn't hold more weight then a user with 500 reputation?).  Worse, anyone who reads the description on the Community account sees that it is an official Stack Exchange account.  They would think that it is Stack Exchange itself (or an employee sending it from the community account), and with good reason, unless they happened to read this post.

### 2. It's anonymous

Users who send this are not responsible for their comments.  Say a user were to have a personal feud with a user, or with a specific tag (such as not liking a particular programming language).  They could choose "Question is unclear" on every question that meets that criteria, with little fear of retribution.

### 3. Replies are broken

Users could be very confused by this.  They make a post that has too much code, and someone who reviews it would send the appropriate comment.  They try to ask how to shorten it, but don't get a response.  This could encourage reviewers to not care as much about a comment, due to not having to reply or be responsible in any way for it.

### 4. Users without knowledge of the new review queue workflow could think it's an auto-comment

Since Community is a bot, it would be reasonable to assume a comment from Community would be based on an algorithm, not a human review.

### 5. You can upvote your own comment.

The strange thing is, you can't unupvote it.

---

What is the reason for having comments be from Community?

Comment: What? Did you want them to be from @Anonymous instead? ;-)

Comment: On a more serious note though, I've [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369062#comment1231333_369062) that I don't like the fact that it's posted under the Community user's name. I think there should be a different way to communicate the fact that this is an automated comment based on review.

Comment: **mostly* anonymous

Comment: @KevinB What do you mean?

Comment: the timestamp and review are visible in the timeline, and will match up with the comment's timestamp

Comment: @KevinB Good point, but it's still a problem; on a site like Stack Overflow, it could go unnoticed for a long time, possibly forever...

Comment: I agree 100% with this. The loss of accountability and dubious aura of authority are really bad. All comments should belong to their authors so they can be meaningfully challenged. This turns review into a throwaway task

Comment: @41686d6564 No, not Anonymous (although Community is anonymous). They should be by the reviewer, attributed as "X - from review" as they used to be (which would presumably satisfy your second comment). To make them Community comments is ill-thought-out and counterproductive.

Comment: I think I might repost all of this with the last line removed and flagged [bug], since the process has several fundamental design flaws.

Answer (score 26):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

#### Make failing an audit only possible *after* selecting a feedback option and attempting to submit the dialog

I've gotten the "STOP! Look and Listen" message twice so far after choosing the "Share feedback" option when I actually **didn't intend to post the comment**. I just needed to open the dialog to test something. Can you please make failing the audit only occur at the final stage of submitting a feedback?

This is **not only useful for testing**. If someone actually encounters an audit while reviewing and they decided to click "Share feedback" to see what canned comments are available and to check if any of them is applicable, it's not fair to make them fail the audit when they intended to go back if they didn't find something applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't new. One has been able to fail or pass an audit by any attempt to interact with the post or modals before submitting the review (pressing "I'm done" or "No actions needed") for a long time.

Comment: Can you please submit this as a separate feature request? We're not going to be able to implement this in this round of bug fixes but I agree with you that it's worth revisiting.

Comment: @kristinalustig as far as I can tell this existing feature request fits: ["STOP! Look and Listen" audit tricked me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/165773), "The only way to increase review count... is to click specific button(s) like I'm Done or No Action Needed - as long as this did not happen, it is wrong to assume test completed..."

Comment: Yeah, it does fit. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 25):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Thanks for the update, Lisa, and all the work the team(s) have put in on the review queues!

I will say I'm most disappointed that you have decided to abandon the plan for expanding/improving filtering options in the queues, specifically the options to:

- Select tags you *don't* want to see review items for
- Select more than three tags for questions you *do* want to see

In my opinion, these two changes would have made the most impact to the Close/Reopen review queues out of everything (except for perhaps the "significant edit" change, which I look forward to seeing in action). I hope you'll reconsider implementing those two key features soon.

EDIT - This is now a standalone feature request here: [Please re-consider adding the ability to select 'ignored' tags in the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369057/please-re-consider-adding-the-ability-to-select-ignored-tags-in-the-review-que)

Comment: Are they concretely abandoned or more of a "not yet" thing?

Comment: Overhauling the filters and working on a new My Tasks view is completely off the roadmap and we don't have plans to come back to it. That said, if there are specific items (like a negative tag filter) that you would like to suggest as one-off features, please post a new feature-request. If there is enough demand for something, we can reconsider. However, adding more tags is something that most likely wont happen - the query perf for these can go way down with more tags, and the tag filtering (especially with more than one tag) is used by only a very miniscule percentage of reviewers.

Comment: @YaakovEllis "the tag filtering (especially with more than one tag) is used by only a very miniscule percentage of reviewers" Interesting. I thought most top-reviewers used this feature.

Comment: @Berriel "most top reviewers" can use the feature and still be a very small percentage of total reviewers. While not the best contextual representation of the picture, consider there are quite possibly as many *total* reviewers (e.g. folks who have done at least 1 review) as there are reviews done by the top reviewers altogether. If I had to guess I would say *regular* usage of the tag filters is probably around 1 to 3%. Of course, I strongly believe if the 'ignored tags' feature existed, it would get used a *lot* more.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I'm disappointed that the filters were not expanded to cover closure sub-reasons (suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347070/184688)). Is it infeasible, or just not worth the dev time? (I didn't press harder at the time because the response indicated that it was already being implemented.) There's a lot regarding the user-facing side of filters that can be built up client-side using userscripts, but there's useful features that can only be achieved with database-level filtering.

Comment: @E.P. more not worth the dev time. Filters are hardly used at all, and creating special filters for different queues would take quite some time. Also, some types of new filtering will require more fundamental changes to the review queue queries which right now are some of the most expensive in the sytem (this is a reason why we limit tag filters to three, btw). So it is not just adding the UI - some filter changes require significant backend work. If filters were widely used then there would be more of a reason to do this. But as it is…

Comment: @YaakovEllis That sounds (partly) like a reverse view on the problem -- another way to see it is "filters are not used enough; how can their UI and functionality be expanded to make people use them more?" ;-). Filters used to be *extremely* hard to discover, and I would bet that the improved discoverability in the new UI will significantly increase their usage. But still, it's a fair point. Thanks for the quick and clear feedback.

Comment: @E.P. I understand (and we talked about this factor as well). Another factor here is that we have been working on Review Queues for a year and a half now and the team needs to move on to other things (like all of the Outdated Answers stuff). This is  not to say that we aren't going to touch this, and we will never work on filters or My Tasks. So if you feel strongly - put in a new feature request and hopefully it can get good feedback and votes. (contd)

Comment: @E.P. (contd)  Suggestion: better to put in smaller, more concrete FRs addressing specific areas where there is reason to think that we can see big improvements, and try to back it up. Much easier for us to find time to work on smaller items versus "Please upgrade all the filters" (which ends up being a much much larger project).

Answer (score 24):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When finishing 20 reviews, in the [First Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) review queue, there's no actual text to tell you, you've completed the daily limit.

[image]

Comment: Already status-planned: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369035/798831, just an empty banner.

Comment: This is actually a different string than the one reported elsewhere. Also gonna get this one out today.

Comment: I pushed this fix out today, so it will be live either today or Monday, depending on how confident we are to push to production on a Friday afternoon. :)

Comment: @kristinalustig: FYI: I assume this will be addressed by your fix, since it sounds like it's just a missing string token from e.g. a localization file, but this issue _also_ appears on [the `/review` page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), where this message is similarly displayed below the appropriate review queue.

Comment: @kristinalustig: FYI: The empty textbox also exists at `Your daily reviews 40 /40`

Comment: @kristinalustig This appears to have broken again.  Reported in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369614/165261

Comment: @kristinalustig: Is this the same as [this similar bug on the main review queues page](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11757/33569)?

Answer (score 23):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "edit" option is still missing in "First answers" queue.

I can't both edit the answer and leave feedback at the same time.

Comment: We're talking more about this - and more generally about taking multiple actions in this queue - on Monday. It's a totally valid point, updates on the status forthcoming.

Comment: You can do this now! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

I just realized something. I do not know if for now this is so, but I do not see it very correct. I am a user of the Stack Overflow community in Spanish and I have seen an automatic community comment, but this one is in English. Is this correct?

But the dialog box is also in English:

[image]

I have also seen that these comments cannot be deleted or edited, which would be a bit annoying since the official language is Spanish.

You can see the comment [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479432/no-puedo-acceder-a-un-campo-de-la-respuesta-quiero-acceder-al-campo-estado-para#comment853515_479432).

Comment: Was the dialog also in English or was it localized?

Comment: the dialog box is in english

Comment: You should probably include that in the answer. You selected an English comment from the dialog, which is a good indication that the posted comment will be in English. Still a bug though, I believe.

Comment: I assume you need to ask the folks that help with translation in transifix to find those new strings and offer translations for them.

Comment: As I understand it, SE relies on volunteers to translate (commonly site moderators?), or at least update the translations for, the UI elements which SE marks as translatable. The issue here may be just that the specific text has not yet been translated (i.e. the issue will be resolved as soon as a volunteer has the time to add a translation for all the new text in the recent update). On the other hand, it could easily be that SE didn't mark that text as translatable, which would mean the volunteers can't add a translation for it until SE adds it as translatable.

Comment: @Makyen sure, but the dialog box also in english

Comment: @Christian As I understand it, the dialog and comments being in English is fully consistent with either of the two possibilities I presented. That doesn't mean that it doesn't need to be fixed, just that it's either something which hasn't been done *yet* within the normal pipeline for localized sites (probable), or that SE forgot about including these portions of text in what can be translated (possible, as it does happen).

Comment: These strings do need to be translated - as of yet, they're still really new and the community hasn't gotten to it yet. I'm sorry about the delay!

Comment: I'm an active user in SOpt and we're facing the same issues there. TBH, I'm getting tired of this "_SE changes site -> messages are in English -> community translates_" cycle. It baffles me that this site (one of the most accessed in the world) can't find a better solution for internationalization - one that doesn't require the community to act **after** changes are made...

Comment: @hkotsubo I hear you. Many times when we change an existing string only slightly, we use a translation fallback so that it still returns the old translated string until the new one is translated. That doesn't resolve situations like these where there are entire paragraphs of text that aren't translated. I totally agree that this is an accessibility issue and isn't fair to users of SOpt, SOjp, etc. I'm not sure what I can do about this internally but I'm going to start a conversation about it to see what solutions we may be able to put in place to avoid this sort of gap. Thanks for speaking up.

Comment: @kristinalustig Thank you so much for your reply! I thought about posting a feature request, but unfortunately I don't have any ideas... Anyway, if you come up with something, I'd really appreciate if you could post here in Meta, and I'll be glad to help (by providing feedback, suggestions to improve, etc). Thanks again, I can't wait to see what you'll bring to us!

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

**Custom flags raised in review audits are real**

Also, passing audits is too hard (but that's related to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037/322419) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/322419) which are way more important than the issue I'm pointing out here).

I noticed that a First Question I was reviewing was actually an audit (it had already been deleted) and I was trying to figure out how to pass the audit... downvoting didn't work (I think it should) so I tried flagging... only the custom option was available so I went ahead and wrote something and raised the flag... that still didn't pass the audit (I think it should!) Finally I clicked on the Leave Feedback option and passed (phew).

Then I went to see if my flag was real and sure enough it was. I don't remember that happening before and [apparently it's not what's supposed to happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327898/6192153)?

Comment: I spent some time trying to reproduce this in my developer environment, but wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I tried this several times, including adding a flag to an audit where the original post was deleted. Would you be able to let me know when the last time you encountered this was, or a link to any of the posts where this happened for you? I'm wondering if there's some extra conditions necessary for this bug to happen and just need that extra troubleshooting information  Let me know and I'll try to dig in more!

Comment: @KylePollard oh... maybe it automagically got fixed! [Here's the post where I encountered this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354978/not-a-question-just-linux-fun-after-an-exam-stand-by). I've just been through all the posts in the queues that have a flag button available and I didn't find any audits to test. I'll have another look on Wednesday. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Clicking the "Learn more" button in a review queue's Stats or History pages simply does nothing.

Ordinarily, this opens up a panel with a "Hey, congrats, you can now use this queue!" panel, but if the user hasn't actually earned the privilege to use that queue, nothing happens.

Here's an example from the Suggested Edits queue on Arqade:

[image: Gif of me pressing the Learn more button to no avail]

I suppose this is meant to actually open up the onboarding modal like it correctly does from the "Review tasks" page on each queue.

Comment: Seems this is the old bug [“Learn more” link in review queue page is not responding on “Stats” and “History” tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364367/312043)

Comment: In a given queue, the Learn more button should actually re-open the modal on the page that shows all the introductory information for the queue. Are you getting any sort of console error regarding the modal? I can't repro this currently.

Comment: In a queue that I *have the reputation to use*, then what you describe happens as expected, @kristinalustig . In a queue that I don't have the reputation to use, simply nothing happens. There are no console errors generated.

Comment: That's odd - When I view the close votes queue here on MSE in incognito, it loads properly. The same is true with Suggested edits. I tried it on Arqade, too and it worked just fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD6Tp.png

Comment: Can't repro here either, not even for queues where my test user doesn't have permissions. Doing a bit more checking around to see if anyone else here can.

Comment: @Catija Huh, I've reproduced that behavior as well. Is it possible that you need to be logged into an account, but just not have the privilege? Edit: Strange that Lristina can't repro on a test user.

Comment: Do you have any userscripts on your non-incognito windows that might be intercepting the modal?

Comment: @Catija I've disabled them and am still experiencing the same thing. However, I've noticed just now that the modal DOES appear from the "Review tasks" page, but NOT from the Stats and History pages. Gif: https://i.imgur.com/iQf1DA2.gif

Comment: I'm able to confirm that the modal doesn't pop up when I'm in incognito on the stats page. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Comment: I can also repro this now, specifically on Gaming stackexchange. I spent a while digging through the code trying to find some reason why this isn't happening and I'm coming up empty. Going to put this in status-review and spend some more time today and tomorrow trying to find the root cause.

Comment: Are you sure it's just the queues that you can't review and not solely dependant on the tab? A [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369053/348196) was just reported. Could it be the same bug?

Comment: @41686d6564 You're right, I had thought it was working from those pages but it's not... Odd. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I originally reported this issue when the first update to the review queues was released. This is *definitely* dependent on the chosen tab.

Comment: if anyone needs a hand in understanding why the modal does not open in other tabs: the "review-v2-transpiled.en.js" file containing the script that controls modal opening is only loaded when you are on the "review tasks" tab. It is not loaded anywhere else (because it is not included in the pages that are loaded when switching to these tabs) - hence no functionality. That's it, no mystery there.

Comment: Yeah, figured out that the modal html was in ReviewTask instead of ReviewNav. Going to do some juggling and get this fixed, but might not get to it until next week. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: I shipped a fix for this today, so it should be live either later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

###### The "Delete" button doesn't work properly in "Late Answers".

As a 20k+ user, I see the "Delete" button; I believe this appears as "Recommend Deletion" to those reviewers with < 20k reputation (as in "Low Quality Answers"). However, when trying this option on a zero-scored answer, I see a **"You cannot delete this post"** message, and I have nothing to do but "Skip" (well, I suppose I *could* downvote, refresh, then "Delete").

In the "Low quality" queue, I *can* "Delete" zero-scored posts (or, at least, I could before the changes – yet to test it since) but, for those with *positive* scores, the button label changes to "Recommend deletion".

Should this be the same for "Late Answers"?

---

EDIT: I've just noticed that label-change (to "Recommend deletion") also happens in the new Late Answers queue for posts with a nett positive score. So, what remains is to: either apply that change also for zero-scored posts; or, as in LQ, allow 20k users to actually cast a delete vote on those.

Comment: I'm starting to look into this right now. In the meantime, are you able to share with me an example of a post that you tried to delete but got an error message for? Low Quality queue and Late Answers are using the exact same function to dictate delete permissions logic so any problem in one of them is likely to be a problem in both.

Comment: @kristinalustig I can have a look, but I've exhausted my quota for today - can you wait until tomorrow? In the meantime, I found a way to 'trick' the system: I downvote first, then select "Delete" and then (review is now complete), go back and undo my downvote. (But maybe I shouldn't be telling you that I'm doing this ...)

Comment: But the "Delete" button still works in Low quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29715462 Also, I *definitely* tried "Delete" on one post (today) that was zero-scored and it failed.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. That "trick" you just mentioned might actually be a hint as to why it's not working! I'll dig into it a bit more.

Comment: @kristinalustig For example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/214233 It says "**You cannot delete this post**"

Comment: Hah - I figured it out! Deep in the depths of our Delete code was a check to make sure that deletions from review were actually from review, and it just manually checked only for the Low Quality queue instead of for any queue that has the delete functionality built in. I should be able to get this fix out today or tomorrow. Thanks for the examples and details, all.

Answer (score 19):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

In the first answer queue: Pending edit suggestions are not visible and are not taken into account when editing. I just declined a suggest edit in [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29671891) because there is no way to see that an edit is pending and the edit UI doesn't warn you when saving the changes.

For users without full edit privilege, it seems that editing is also not blocked, but they aren't able to save it, as explained on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411050/first-questions-can-choose-edit-as-action-but-the-edit-queue-is-full).

Comment: A note: that is a first **questions** review, not a first answers review.

Comment: From what I understand, it is the same in both queues.

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When reviewing First Questions, I often see something I can improve to the question. I choose the Edit action, submit the edit, and then I'm already taken to the next review queue item. I might want to upvote the question or leave a comment, and I have to go back in order to do that. I prefer the old workflow in the First Posts queue, which allowed you to do multiple actions in any order you like.

Comment: Is this the same as Dharman's comment on his report here? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369045/253521 re: "*I can't both edit the answer and leave feedback at the same time.*"

Comment: @TylerH yeah, more or less. I searched for "First Questions" but it applies to "First Answers" too, it seems.

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> #### 2. New actions for Late answers queue
>
> The Late answers queue has been successful in identifying and removing low quality posts, repeat answers, and spam. Reviewers were able to take any number of actions on a task, so the objective of this queue wasn’t all that obvious. To clear up any ambiguity and focus on identifying problematic answers, we’ve defined three actions: Looks OK, Edit, and Delete.

Looks like that change isn't deployed yet:

[image]

Review item: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29668488 (it has a higher number than other review queue items from after the changes, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29668209)

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel! I fully missed turning on that setting (in the sea of 25 settings we needed to turn on for this launch). It should be turned on now.

Answer (score 16):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

#### Update the pages that reference the now-retired first posts queue

Some examples of pages that do this:

- [What are review queues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro)
- [How do I use the First posts queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-posts)
- [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390)
- [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538)
- [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226)

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm reviewing a (not-an) answer in the First Answers review queue. After flagging and downvoting it, I realize 'Looks OK' and 'Edit' don't apply, so I choose 'Share feedback'. None of the comments apply, so I don't select one of the radio buttons, so I click the 'Share feedback' button anyway, and I'm greeted with an error message:

> An error occurred when submitting your feedback. Please try again.

[image]

Comment: Is the bug you're reporting that it's a toast with a generic error message instead of a validation message or that there's no review action for non-answers? If it's the former, great. If it's the latter, that was reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/348196) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037/348196).

Comment: @41686d6564 two bugs: I want to leave *another* comment which counts as feedback, and I don't expect the 'Share feedback' to be enabled if I don't select an option.

Comment: I have encountered this several times... I've already left a constructive comment on the NAA, flagged etc. but then cannot "complete the review task". Frustrating (and puts me off reviewing).

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The modals for these two new queues don't seem to be movable like modals in the other review queues are. Sometimes I like to drag them out of the way by their title section.

Is this deliberate?

Tested on Stack Overflow with Firefox 92.0b8 and Chrome 92.0.4515.159 on Windows 10.

This impacts the new reopen modal as well.

Comment: Ugh, yes the modals absolutely need to be draggable!

Comment: Not intentional - I'll look into it to see what's happened.

Comment: @kristinalustig hint: `controller` on the dataset should be `se-draggable` (on the `.s-modal--dialog` element) pulse the `se-draggable-target` should be set to `handle` on the element that is the handle for the drag behaviour

Comment: as a preview: [and voila](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nwyj.gif)

Comment: I fixed this today, it should be live either today or tomorrow.

Comment: @kristinalustig yay, we will be able to drag the modal around :) On a more serious note - thank you! Was the above a correct guess?

Comment: @kristinalustig, thanks for fixing the modals in the two new queues! Before this issue was resolved, but somewhat after posting this answer, I edited it to note that this also affects the new repoen modal. That modal still cannot be moved. Any chance we can fix it, too?

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Verified in first answers, not sure if it holds elsewhere but I imagine it does.

I stumbled over a link-only answer, and my first instinct is to downvote and flag. Voting is fine. The flag menu, however, acts as if the post is deleted (which, in this case, it was), only giving "in need of moderator intervention". Only deleted posts give one option, which is a dead giveaway that the post is an audit.

Aside being a dead giveaway that the post is an audit, combined with the lack of being able to flag and then go on to "I'm done" means there's not a sane way to end the review, even if the flag dialog was present. I've flagged a couple real answers and I have no idea what to press afterwards. There's no applicable feedback, "looks OK" is wrong, and so is edit. Allegedly, this part is [supposed to be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/332043), but I don't see any change in the available options, and flagging isn't enough to complete the review (which is a massive regression, in my opinion. You used to be able to vote and flag, and pick "I'm done" to move on).

[image: image showing the flag popup in first answers only containing "in need of moderator intervention"]

Ended up clicking "share feedback" just to end it, which also doesn't make sense as a pass case for this particular type of posts given the current feedback options. There's not really any good way to handle audits at the moment, though. [Here's the audit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29682951) (10k+? on Stack Overflow), for anyone interested.

Comment: That also holds true for blatant never-to-be-on-topic first questions, such as identification questions on Movies.SE

Comment: This has at least *partially* been addressed now that the "Other action" option is there, but the "ending a review after a flag" problem sort of still exists, pending the solution to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369837/other-action-in-first-answers-doesnt-fully-complete-the-review).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as completed as we've added back in the ability to complete a review after finishing another action. I also fixed the bug related to the other action option that's referenced above. I realize that it's a giveaway that the post is an audit, but that particular issue we're going to defer.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29670070

After flagging:

[image]

[image]

I got the 'Thanks. We'll look at it' banner. And that's it.

I also left a comment, yet still have the 'Share feeback' option available. I had no choice but to Skip this as there was no other valid option.

Comment: Already reported for the "First questions" queue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037/348196

Comment: Very related, for first answers that are NAA like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/165261

Comment: What's the point of your edit? If you tried to just bump with "empty" edit, that's a wrong way.

Comment: I'm just picky like that. I hate leaving words out, and am constantly reviewing my own posts for grammar or other errors (as well as posts by others). It's just my nature. And it wasn't an empty edit. I added the word 'banner'.

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Undo accidental wrong feedback

I stumbled across question that needs to provide some codes, so I clicked the share feedback button:

[image]

I wanted to click "Question needs some code", but I accidentally clicked the "question is too broad" option and shared the wrong feedback to the user.

Is there a way I could undo the feedback? Because I can't seem to do anything with the comment.

Comment: You can flag the comment as no longer needed, that way a moderator can delete it. Otherwise the comment is owned by the Community user, and thus not modifieable by you.

Comment: @Luuklag i just tried to review a post and flag the community comment and nope i cant flag the comment. It says "This comment will be automatically removed when post is corrected" when i tried to flag it

Comment: [I have a request about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369050/348196). Hopefully, it'll be considered. - _"nope i cant flag the comment"_: This has also been [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067/348196).

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the new *First Questions* review queue, if you cast a close vote (i.e., by flagging a question) and it passes the threshold to actually close the question, then it will refresh the page to include the closed message, and add:

> You are not able to review this item

It makes perfect sense that a question that is now closed would be removed from the review queue. And it makes sense to provide immediate feedback to the flagger that the question is now closed. **But I would *also* expect that voting to close a question would qualify as already having reviewed that question.**

I assume this only applies to people who have the *cast close and reopen votes* privilege (3,000 reputation).

[image]

Comment: FYI: While this is still marked as [tag:status-review], I believe this is now [tag:status-completed]. At least, on Stack Overflow it no longer completes a review when a question is closed, and allows the reviewer to continue with the new _Other Action_ option.

Answer (score 13):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Don't know if you are aware of that but currently, Triage blocks questions from getting to close queue for about a day average. I think this is [a bit too much](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410977/839601):

> ...we get the situation when system correctly and quickly detects most troublesome questions and then, essentially shields them from getting to close queue - for a full day average, go figure.
>
> This is really *really* weird. The way how things work now, system essentially incentivises askers of poor questions to [pay money for fraudulent release of asking limits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410831/839601). Seeing multiple poor questions hanging open and seemingly unattended for days can only convince them that their ban is mere misfortune and that it makes sense to try their luck again...

I would appreciate if you could do something about that.

Probably least effort consuming option to address above issue would be to allow questions getting to close queue while they are on triage (possibly with some reasonably small delay, if you prefer).

Comment: Sounds like if I vote to close a question that's in the triage queue, it should go immediately to the close vote queue (and either skip triage or just be in both).

Comment: @doppelgreener if you remember, initial design of the triage assumed that triaged questions aren't visible to anyone except for triage reviewers. The fact that it currently is blocked from getting to any other review naturally follows from this initial (unfortunately [abandoned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/839601)) design

Comment: @kristinalustig just in case if you prefer to have a separate feature request for this matter - it is linked in my post from words "a bit too much"

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Message for reaching daily quota is blank for the "First questions" queue

Today, I reviewed twenty First questions and as much Suggested edits at the [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site. Now, when I look at [Review queues](https://math.stackexchange.com/review) page, I see that there is a light blue rectangle below **Suggested edits** (see the picture below), in which it is written “Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 8 hours to continue reviewing.” So far, nothing is new. But below **First questions** there is also a blue rectangle… with nothing written in it.

[image]

Comment: Been seeing a lot of those...

Comment: Reproduced for me.

Comment: Hi there - this should be fixed. Please let me know if you're still seeing this blank message.

Comment: @kristinalustig No, I don't see those blank messages anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Can the 'Edit' option be disabled if you don't have the privilege to edit all posts and suggesting an edit is not possible (because the suggested edits queue is full, or you have already too many pending suggested edits)?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on meta.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411050/8967612

Answer (score 13):

The removal of the "I'm Done" option from the **Late Answers** queue raises some issues:

We can no longer:

- Vote up/down
- Flag as Rude/Spam or for moderator attention
- Leave a comment

As a review action.

If this is not intentional - please add an "I'm Done" button or anything similar.

If this is intentional (maybe these are not intended to be actions in this queue and I missed that) - then this queue falls back to be identical to the Low Quality Answers review queue. Is *this* intended? It certainly feels like a weird and confusing duplication. You said, regarding the Late Answers queue:

> The Late answers queue has been successful in identifying and removing low quality posts, repeat answers, and spam. Reviewers were able to take any number of actions on a task, so **the objective of this queue wasn’t all that obvious**. To clear up any ambiguity and focus on identifying problematic answers, we’ve defined three actions: Looks OK, Edit, and Delete.

To me, the objective of the queue is even less obvious now. If its purpose is to remove low quality posts - we already have a queue for that. If its purpose is to remove repeated answers - we didn't really get the tools for that (not NAA and none of the recommend deletion options applies). If its purpose is to remove spam - we could already flag spam before and it doesn't really require a deletion option (enough flags will delete the post anyway).

So, what ***is*** the current objective of the queue?

Answer (score 13):

## Anonymous comments: They're bad

The thing I like about reviewing on SE, and why I think it works so well, is that it's *human*. You can ask what's wrong with your post, and quite often get helpful feedback pretty quickly. There's transparency, so you can see exactly what's going on with your post (and who's doing it).

Giving reviewers the option to post anonymous feedback goes very much against this. It sounds like a good idea on the surface, but all it does is introduce issues. When I comment under a post with things that need to be fixed, I have never once had second thoughts because of worries about my name being associated with that. I put a lot of effort in to ensure my comments are helpful, and if I'm asked for clarification I want to be there to help.

Anonymous comments mean the feedback given will always be a bit too vague to really be helpful. One size fits all doesn't fit anyone. Even worse, if the post author cares enough to try to improve it, they can't reach me to get help doing that. To add on to the problems, if these comments are misused, there's currently no way to flag them (as far as I can tell). That's not rare either, I've seen it multiple times already (not maliciously, just incorrect usage).

If automated, useless comments become the norm for reviewing, it'll only reinforce the idea that SO is unwelcoming to new users. Robots are...robotic. Nobody who's new to the site wants to be greeted by being told there's something generally wrong, without being told or being able to ask for specifics.

If these comments were only ever used when appropriate, they'd be fine. But the problem is, the people who use these canned comments often will be the same people who won't take the time to actually weigh whether or not leaving specific feedback would be better. It just gives reviewers the option to be lazy, in a part of the site where laziness will 100% lead to a worse site all around.

This feature feels like a poorly thought out tool to help review grinders grind faster, and it doesn't feel appropriate for any site other than SO (where effiency and quantity of reviews is necessarily much more of a priority than other sites). Please, **please** get rid of it.

Comment: I'm of two minds on this.  On one hand, I completely agree: these comments are often not very good.  On the other hand, new users can't see close votes on their questions, so they lack the feedback that someone thinks something is wrong with their question until it's closed (which can take a long time, delaying the feedback cycle).  So getting them _some_ feedback sooner is good, and at least the canned comments are better advice than what people post themselves ("What have you tried so far?", "Please read [ask]", "SO is not a free coding website", etc.).

Comment: Perhaps the answer is just that we need _more_ canned comments, to match the expressiveness of the close reasons.  The low-quality answers queue (mostly) handles this well: there are canned comments for (most of) the most common issues.  Expanding the comments (and making them site-specific, like close reasons are) would go a long way to making them a bit more useful.

Comment: I agree with @RyanM, although [I disagree that the close reasons are expressive enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367058/273494). Canned feedback wouldn’t be so bad if they were less terse, and if we could “mix and match” instead of have to pick just one piece of feedback to give.

Comment: @RyanM The problem is, on SO it might be normal to see somewhat useless comments by reviewers (like "What have you tried so far?"). But on other sites, where reviewers should be able to take much more time to give personalized and useful feedback, these canned comments just give reviewers an option to quickly and easily give that exact sort of bad feedback. Site customizability for the comments, and more variety, might help the issue a lot, as long as other issues like not being able to flag or reply to the comments are addressed.

Comment: @RyanM "need more canned comments" - oh, you know, like the extensive lists folks acquired using the famous ARC userscript, for example? :) As an idea, SE could examine what [SOCVR](https://userscripters.github.io/socvr-auto-comments/) serves (not saying that every comment template is gold, but still...).

Comment: It doesn't matter if the site it big or small. If one wants to review, then one should review, not get it done as fast as possible using a canned comment that doesn't even help the user that the comment is intended for.

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Display site-specific close reasons in the Reopen queue**

When reviewing a question that was closed for a site-specific reason, the display in the reopen queue simply shows (e.g. on Stack Overflow):

[image]

without stating if it was closed for "seeking recommendations", or for "needing debugging details", etc.

This means if I decide to leave the post closed, I need to navigate to the post in order to see which reason was used, in order to decide whether "the original close reason was unresolved" or if I need to pick a different reason.

These additional actions are time consuming. Also, I've been tempted to just choose "the original close reason was unresolved" without verifying what that was, which is not ideal.

Please display this information on the page itself, preferably just below the above message.

Answer (score 11):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

One quick thing, everything looks good on a glance through! Can the First Posts queue be moved out of the way to a section at the bottom like what is done with "Retired Badges"? Similarly "First Posts" now probably doesn't warrant showing in the review queue drop down from the top bar.

Comment: It'll be moved out of the way in a couple of weeks. We're making sure that the queue gets fully emptied out before we fully disable it so that no posts get lost in the void.

Comment: At least on Stack Overflow, this queue is no longer displayed, so I _believe_ this is now completed. (Acknowledging it may still persist on other sites where I don't yet have reviewer privileges?)

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On Stack Overflow, if I go to the First Questions or Answers queue, I see this:

[image]

Because I don't have the required reputation to review in that queue.  But the empty blue banner should look like this, as it does in the other queues there (which I also don't have access to):

[image]

As it does in the other queues, e.g:

[image]

This also happens if a sub-X reputation user looks back at previous review tasks such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/296686100), which are useful if you need to flag as NAA-, spam, etc.  Again, this only happens with the First Answers or Questions review queues, not the Late X ones.

Comment: Good catch, we missed implementing this message for the new queues. Getting that in today. Thanks!

Comment: Just pushed this fix this morning so it should be live either later today or Monday.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T35EB.jpg) and the [Help Center page](/help/review-first-posts) for First Posts, mention that it's retired (and add links to its successors).

Comment: First Posts queue help center page has been replaced by First questions and First answers, and if people go to the First posts review queue, they see a message that the queue has been retired.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Phrasing nitpick(s)**:

The Help center page for the Low quality queue says:

> **Note**: On Stack Overflow, low quality answers are exclusively handled in the Low quality answers queue. You will not see questions in this queue.

This sounds like it's saying that the Low quality answers queue is the only place that handles low quality answers (when really, answers are also handled in other queues), when really it's that the queue only handles answers.  It should probably be something like:

> **Note**: On Stack Overflow, the Low quality answers queue exclusively handles low quality answers. You will not see questions in this queue.

---

Also, ideally "Low-quality posts" and "Low quality answers" would be hyphenated the same way.  I think the technically correct answer is hyphenated, but it's really the inconsistency that bothers me here.

---

<sup>Yes, these are both super nitpicky.</sup>

Comment: Minor nitpick:  These are too nitpicky, but OK anyway.

Comment: I’m I the only one that thinks the capitalization of Low-quality is weird? If it’s a name, the entire name should be capitalized yeah? And yes, I’m a certified class-A nitpicker, and no, I don’t think think this feedback is super nitpicky, but I may be the minority opinion :)

Comment: I agree with that feedback - fixed.

Comment: @ColleenV [Our styles](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing) require sentence case for headings - so we only capitalize the first word.

Comment: But it’s not sentence case to capitalize in the middle of a sentence…? It should be set off in quotes or something if you aren’t marking it as a name of something with caps. “ On Stack Overflow, low quality answers are exclusively handled in the *Low quality answers queue*…” The point of punctuation and capitalization is to convey information, and within a sentence your style fails to do that and looks like a mistake. A name is not a heading. @Catija

Comment: The "Low quality" answers queue is the name of the queue - with that exact capitalization. It's out of context in the sentence but I don't know that means we should change how we capitalize it. We're duplicating the heading on the page when we refer to it as an entity rather than merely talking about low quality answers in general. @ColleenV We do this pretty consistently, even if it's not common elsewhere.

Comment: I am confused by the quotes around “Low quality”.. is that the entire name? Headings aren’t names. You don’t use headings in sentences without setting the off from the rest of the text. Names should be capitalized so people know which words are part of the name and which words are part of the sentence. I’m pretty sure that’s not controversial orthography. @Catija

Comment: And, if you’re just using attributives, none of it should be capitalized. It would be fine to write low quality answers, close, reopen, and first posts queues.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Answers I have already reviewed in the First Answers queue reappear for me in the Late Answers queue.** I believe this is not the intended behaviour, since in the past an answer I reviewed in the First Posts queue would no longer show up in the Late Answers queue for me. In any case, it does not seem to make sense for a single user to review the same post twice.

Comment: Are you able to share a link to an example of this? It will make it much easier for me to hunt down the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @kristinalustig I think the following two were one instance: https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/103464, https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/103466 . But I am not 100% sure now since the answer has been deleted and I cannot view its review in Late Answers since I skipped it (not wanting to review twice). Will comment here if I find more.

Comment: There was at least one other time, but I did not save the links unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.

Comment: I figured out this bug - should have a fix in today or tomorrow. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: @kristinalustig That's great to hear, thank you.

Comment: Hi @kristinalustig, just wanted to let you know that the bug still exists (in case it was supposed to have been fixed already, if not please ignore). Latest example: https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/104712, https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/104714

Comment: I shipped this fix yesterday, so it may have gone live just after you experienced it. Could you let me know if it happens again?

Comment: @kristinalustig Sure. Thank you.

Comment: @kristinalustig Here's an example from today where it seems to have happened again: https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/104803, https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/104807

Comment: @kristinalustig This bug still happens regularly.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Agh, a zombie bug! If you're able, could you please create a separate bug report meta post with an example or two? That will make it much easier for tracking/assignment workflows.

Comment: @kristinalustig So just a few links to review items in each queue done on the same post by the same person?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yup, whatever is necessary to adequately demonstrate that the bug is still occurring would be perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

When I follow a post, and Share Feedback in one of the new queues, [Community](/users/-1) posts a comment on my behalf. Because it's a comment not posted by *me*, I immediately get a notification in my inbox. Could those be suppressed please?

Comment: Related: [Exclude Community actions from popping up as "moderator actions" on the Moderator dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369060/348196).

Comment: Re: This and other answers concerning the comments from Community: Maybe the Bot is looking for the Pundit badge?

Comment: Looked into this today, and I'm going to defer it for now, as it would take a decent amount of work and introduces complexity to what I'm pretty sure is an edge case (in that, I'm assuming you don't follow every question you share feedback on). Please let me know if I'm mistaken and I'll revisit.

Comment: @kristinalustig no problem, it's just a minor inconvenience.

Answer (score 11):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)/[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Let individual sites decide whether they are a "code-related site" for the purposes of the code-specific canned Community comments**

kristinalustig [remarked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release?page=1&tab=votes#comment1231189_369018) that the code-specific canned Community comments are supposed to be available only on "code-related sites". However, it is unclear to me how it is determined whether a site is code-related. I'd like this to be an option that the sites can decide for themselves, as it is not always obvious whether a site prefers their posts to contain code. For example,  [posting code should generally be avoided on Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/65/65339). While a site probably has to decide only once whether they want to be 'code-related', it would be nice if this is a setting that e.g. the CM's can touch.

Comment: And, I suspect the sensible default, amusingly enough should be that sites are *not* code related. Citation needed, but I'd bet a sock on it

Comment: CMs can already touch this. I think that Catija is planning on communicating with site mods about this, but it is definitely configurable (not sure if `status-completed` is the most appropriate, since it is already fulfilled. whatever.)

Comment: @YaakovEllis I couldn't tell whether this was a configurable setting, due to the bug that enabled the Community comments on all(?) sites. So I wanted to check whether this was done. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Here's a Physics meta question about a Community comment that mentions code: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13790/123208

Comment: @YaakovEllis, Still haven't heard anything about how to 'configure' this. Is this planned?

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

On the Code Review site one of the options for First Questions is `Share Feedback`. It has 2 options that mostly only represent Stack Overflow. The old workflow allowed any comment from the reviewer to be used as shared feedback but that is no longer an option. There are more reasons on Code Review on how a question can be improved.

The `Community comments` don't really represent the CR community and I can't flag it for moderator attention, and the moderator can't delete the comment.

I see this as a bug.

Comment: You mean a diamond moderator cannot delete the comment by Community?

Comment: @Unconsidered Exactly, a duly elected moderator can not delete the comment by the Community.

Comment: On Stack Overflow at least, I can flag one of those comments for [moderator attention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGadR.png).

Comment: @Unconsidered Opening the flag dialogue does not seem to be the issue. Flagging the comment (by pressing the "Flag comment" button) [seems to be the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067).

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I can't perform the most important action in "First answers queue". I can't flag the answer for deletion or vote to delete it myself. How can I push the post into "Low Quality Answer" review?

[image]

Comment: I guess your and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369017/1052107) is same so there was no need of this answer I feel

Comment: Does this actually say "Del-pls" or did you change that for the screenshot?

Comment: @Anonymous It does say. I forgot to disable userscripts for this screenshot.

Comment: @Dharman Just curious, which userscript is that?

Comment: @Anonymous https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/CVRG-Mak-new-version/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js

Comment: The post menu is fixed for this queue and you should be able to flag and then mark yourself as having completed your review.

Answer (score 10):

We have a problem at SO.es (I supposed Ja, Po, and Ru has the same issue)

On the first question queue, we have only 2 motives to close a question...

But in all international sites, we have another problem.. question that are not in the official site language...

[image]

So we need a third motive that let close because the question is in another language. This is important for us.

Comment: The same problem should occur on any site (different languages though). It's just maybe in the wrong queue.

Comment: @D4RIO the queue is not wrong.. is a first time user... the problem is not having one of the highest closing motive (at least on international sites) on the selection.. and the ones there, doesn't cover this particular problem....

Answer (score 10):

Honestly not sure if this has been covered already, but it looks like the link to get back to the main Review Queues dashboard has disappeared from the individual queue pages—can we please bring that back, and maybe make it more prominent? Going through the menu is a bit out-of-the-way for me.

Answer (score 9):

One feature I'm REALLY missing here is the possibility to use a custom comment when leaving feedback.

Sure, I can write a custom comment and then press Looks ok. But that would be wrong. I could write a custom comment, press Edit, make some small changes that are not really changes, and then save. But that would also be wrong.

Well, what I can do, as a really clunky workaround, is that I can choose one of the premade comments. Then I hit back in my webbrowser and click the question or answer I just reviewed. And then I delete the comment I chose earlier and write my own. It's possible, and everything turns out right. But it's a VERY clunky thing to do something that is what I want to do for 99% of the questions I don't seem fit for "Looks good".

Comment: You are missing the "I'm Done" button for after writing your custom comment.

Comment: A custom comment? As in posted by Community? :O

Comment: @Unconsidered No, as in that I choose what feedback to leave on my own instead of choosing between the premade comments.

Comment: There's still a "Add a comment", no?

Comment: @Unconsidered Yes, but as I wrote here, then I'm forced to choose between "Looks's good", "Edit" and "Skip". None of these fit, because I want to leave feedback.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Selecting "Other Action" in First Questions or First Answers does not clear the post from the queue

I saw that the "Other Action" option was enabled yesterday for both the First Questions and First Answers queues. However, when I select that option, the review is not marked as completed in the post timeline, and it seems that the post stays in the queue till someone chooses one of the other options. Alternatively, there might be a minimum number of "Other Action" reviews expected for it to be cleared, but that has not been documented yet from what I see.

[Example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/104742) of post staying in queue after two "Other Action" reviews:

[image: Two Other Action reviews]

[Example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/104723) of post cleared after one "Other Action" and one "Looks OK" review:

[image: One Other Action and one Looks OK review]

Comment: @KillingTime Interesting, I went backed and checked my reviews, and I do not observe this. (Example: https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/104707). Perhaps you should add an answer with an example.

Comment: @KillingTime I just realized that you might have meant selecting Edit from the options below the question and closing the review as "Other Action". In that case, yes, the problem persists.

Comment: No, this was using the edit button in the same panel as the "other action", so that it says 'edit' rather than 'reviewed'. Double checking the timeline, this actually created another separate "First Answers" event for the second review so it's a separate bug (which I think has already been reported)...so ignore me, thanks.

Comment: I think any post requires 3 reviewers to be completed regardless of how they action the post. Meaning if the 1st chooses "Looks ok" and a 2nd "Edit" you still need a 3rd reviewer to finish the item.

Comment: @bad_coder No, that's not true. Choosing "Looks OK" or "Edit" immediately completes the review. This was also how it was for the First Posts queue. Example: https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/104843

Comment: @bad_coder Also, it is not just three reviews, here's an example with four: https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/104835

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29782281) is the most I've seen so far, with 12 and counting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Zmv.png

Comment: @zcoop98 Wow...

Comment: This should be fixed (once it gets live): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369947

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [How do I use the First questions queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) page says "answer"

> **Share feedback** if the post has the potential of being a good answer, but cannot be improved by anyone but the post-author. ...

Comment: I've now fixed this (along with a few other minor edits to the text).

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Now that "Significant Edits" are firmly a thing, is there any possibility of [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567/355458) becoming a thing? Non-bumping edits would be a very useful thing to have, and it seems as though the "Significant Edit" feature would be the first step towards implementing this.

Comment: This would have a problem of not alerting the community to potentially problematic edits, and that's why it has never been pursued in the past (the potential for abuse is so high). It would need to be restricted to a higher rep threshold than 2k to be considered, IMO.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I'm aware of the potential for abuse if done incorrectly. I'm simply asking if SE would be open to considering the feature request, given that the ability for the feature to be added is now there

Comment: I think that's a decent idea, but the work to implement that is probably outside the scope of this project. Could you create a separate feature request question for this so that we can track interest and generate further discussion on it?

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Per [Yaakov's recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release?answertab=active#comment1231153_369020), I'm posting this as a specific feature-request:

One of the review queue changes I was most excited to see during our research interview was the option to add an "ignored tags" filter... where we could include tags for questions we absolutely did not want to see review items for. However, it seems like it was completely abandoned almost as soon as it was announced. Please re-consider implementing this killer feature to the close & reopen queues.

Comment: Would you mind posting this as a separate Meta question? Your answer post itself might get lost in the responses here and may not get an accurate picture of how much interest there is for the feature.

Comment: @LisaPark [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369057/please-re-consider-adding-the-ability-to-select-ignored-tags-in-the-review-que)

Comment: Just for my own post-triaging-sake, I'm going to mark this as status-deferred since it has its own post now.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**When logged out, review links for First Questions, First Answers, and Late Answers appear completely greyed out.** This does not happen for the other queues (for me).

[Example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/103462) from First Questions on Academia SE:

[image: First Questions example, greyed out]

On the other hand, an [example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/103278) from the Suggested Edits queue, that appears normal:

[image: Suggested Edits example, normal]

Comment: Do you mean links to specific review *items*? I kind of think they should auto redirect to the main /review page for logged out users. Guests can't review items, and don't really need to know who did what action on a review task anyway.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I mean links to specific reviews. I have added links to the examples I used, they are accessible without being logged in.

Comment: @TylerH I do not know if links to specific items should be accessible when logged out or not (I am not sure how it was before), but at least the behaviour should be consistent across queues. Also, redirection might make a lot of sense, but I don't see the purpose of greying it out.

Comment: I agree with that (no greying out); I'm just thinking out loud about how it might be best handled moving forward.

Comment: Finally got to this particular bug and am not currently able to repro. Is this still happening?

Comment: @kristinalustig Yes, looks like it has been fixed.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Change the text of the "Submit" button to "Continue" if the user chooses a (cancellable) option that has a second step

This is especially useful for the "Share feedback" option (because it opens a modal dialog) but maybe the community should decide if it's a good idea to use it for other options as well (e.g., the "Edit" option).

I think it's more intuitive that way. It will also be in line with my [other request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369121/348196) about failing audits *only* at the last step.

Comment: Yeah, we've gotten this feedback on previous releases as well. We're discussing this today, so we'll have an update on it soon. I agree that this makes more sense.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### First Answers queue - Link to other answers

I have a review where the answer just repeats another answer.

I would like to say this in a comment to the new answer but I can't as there are no share buttons on the Other Answers Page

Comment: I posted a dedicated feature request about this a while ago: [Add the share button to (other) answers in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363704/571958)

Comment: And I see I had already upvoted that request :)

Comment: @YaakovEllis could be nice to get the `status-review` on my linked feature request above if this is indeed the case

Answer (score 8):

A handful of suggestions for "Share feedback":

**Question / answer contains image of code**

Please post your code as text, not an image, so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

**Answer is only a link**

A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link and quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

**Answer doesn't attempt to answer the question**

This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context.

**Question / answer contains meta-commentary**

This post contains content unnecessary to the post.  Please make your posts only about the question you're asking / answer you're proposing.

Comment: Agree with all but the last one, which 1) I don't think is common enough to warrant a canned comment and 2) is generally best fixed by editing out said commentary rather than trying to talk the OP into doing it.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

I was reviewing the **Triage** queue.

When select Spam flag using the button below **audit** questions, the action is treated as if clicked **Looks OK** instead of **Flag**.

What happened:

[image]

It would be great if you can rectify the result in these audits,

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29702035

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29693259

[Original Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/selected-spam-flag-in-triage-but-the-audit-said-i-clicked-looks-ok-with-pro) for reference.

Comment: The flag "link" isn't suppose to be there for Triage. I believe it was added by mistake, when it was added to another review queue. [See my comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#comment1231213_369017). Use the "Flag" option in "The Box" instead.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### User not returned to review queue after edit

---

**Summary**

A change in behaviour (of the Edit link beneath the post).

**Note**: This report is not the same bug/feature request as [Tomerikoo's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369208/571958) which requests the removal of the edit link.

---

**Details**

Previously, in a review queue (any review queue, IIRC, but I am currently seeing this in Late Answers), if you edited a post (*by clicking on the edit link beneath the post*), then once the edit was submitted, you would be *automatically* returned to the review queue to continue/complete the review of that particular item.

However, now, once the edit has been submitted, you are put on to the question's page instead. You have to hit the browser's back button twice, in order to get back to the post that you were reviewing - in order to complete the review (No action needed, I'm done, recommend deletion, etc.).

Also, if you *cancel* the edit, then you are not returned to the review page either, but again you are placed on to the question page.

Why has this changed? Please can we be returned automatically to the review queue, rather than having to click an extra few times on the browser's back button to get back to the review.

Comment: I have already reported this in [this very post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369208/571958)... Instead of posting new duplicate answers it is better to upvote existing ones so they get better traction

Comment: I hadn't seen your post, I *had* checked the [spreadsheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/280335) first. This isn't the most efficient bug tracking tool, you must admit - there is no search mechanism. However, your post deals with two issues, whereas they would have been better separated as two distinct issues. The issue that I report above is somewhat buried in your issue of the two UI edit elements. Also, you request to remove the link beneath the question, but this link has been there for many years, prior to the recent change, so I don't think that it should be removed.

Comment: However, I would agree that both UI elements should perform the same action, and not be different. I have never used the radio button Edit option, so I was unaware of any difference in behaviour. I also think that it is daft to have a duplication of UI elements, although others may disagree - it is similar to the duplication of the [link-only post flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369252/280335)

Comment: The way I see it: As long as there is a dedicated action to finish the review with an edit - this one should be used to edit and therefore the link for edit shouldn't be there at all (similar to First questions and answers). If we should be able to make several actions (as before), then yes - the edit should be done through the link and the behavior should remain as before. It all depends on what direction the dev team is taking with the next changes

Answer (score 8):

After editing, an answer went through the first answers queue multiple times.

[image: post history with a first answers review, an edit, then another review]

This doesn't make sense.  There is only one first answer here, and it could lead to multiple comments from Community, which would be confusing for anyone who doesn't have knowledge of the review process.

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Could you link the answer on which this happened so that it can be more easily investigated?

Comment: @RyanM [Here's the link to the review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29719288).

Answer (score 8):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

When I start to edit [this old question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286262/295232), which until yesterday had only 29 views, I see the new checkbox

> This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.

It seems that box is *always* shown (I don't think that question qualifies for the popularity criterion). How does that work with the edit-to-reopen criteria mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/295232)? Are those obsolete now, and is the only criteria whether this box was ticked or not?

Bonus question: what happens if <s>I</s> my scripts edit a question via the API? Do those ever count for reopening? If so, my scripts might need to be more careful with editing questions.

Answer to that bonus question: those edits don't seem to count for reopening (which is good IMHO). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21282162/timeline) is an example: no Reopen Votes review queue item to be found.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### The "Learn more" button from the Stats and History tabs of *any* review queue does not work

Oddly enough, it *does* seem to work when under any "Review tasks" tab, but under the other two, it does not.

[image]

Comment: Already reported: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369038/348196

Comment: @41686d6564 No, that says "Clicking the "Learn more" button in a review queue **that I do not have access to**", what I am experiencing is happening in queues that I *do* have access to

Comment: It could be something else but it's likely the same bug. That wasn't my downvote BTW. I'm just connecting the two answers so that duplicate/related/similar issues are easy to track.

Comment: I fixed this today - it'll be live today or tomorrow. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 7):

The text in the [help center article for the low-quality posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-low-quality) doesn't match the capitalization according to the [style guide](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing).

**Headings**

| Don’t | Do |
| --- | --- |
| Performance Overview | Performance overview |
| Edit Your Profile | Edit your profile |

**Feature or product names**

| Don’t | Do |
| --- | --- |
| Job Alerts | job alerts |
| Blog | blog |
| Profile | profile |
| Stack Overflow talent | Stack Overflow Talent |
| stack exchange | Stack Exchange |

The heading of the article is mixed case, not sentence cased:

> How do I use the **L**ow-quality posts queue?

This is also inconsistent with the header for the [access review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) page, which is all lower case even though it appears to me to be a header.

References to the feature (low-quality posts queue) are sentence cased, not lower case:

> Posts entering the **L**ow-quality posts queue have been flagged as problematic by users or recognized by the system’s quality checks to be potentially low quality. (Apparently there must be a blank line separating text from tables even if you put a double blank at the end.)

Frankly, it doesn’t appear as if there is a consistent understanding of what is a header and what is a feature name. If you’re going to capitalize something in the middle of a sentence, it shouldn’t be sentence cased unless it is quoted or otherwise distinguished from the rest of the sentence. To do otherwise just makes it unnecessarily difficult to parse the sentence. There are plenty of questions on ELL where a non-native speaker had trouble understanding a sentence because it wasn’t clear which words were modifying other words.

If this wacky "let's treat something like a proper noun, but sentence case it instead of [properly capitalize it](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/capitalization/proper-nouns)" is intentional, which it seems to be based on the review queue help center articles, here's a list of a few pages that don't follow that convention either by (correctly IMO) leaving the feature names as all lower case or capitalizing feature names as if they were proper nouns:

1. [What are **r**eview queues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro)
2. [Why was I suspended from the **R**eview **Q**ueues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-suspensions)
3. [**a**pprove **t**ag wiki edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)
   "other posts in the [**S**uggested **E**dits review task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits)" (*links referring to the new queues are sentenced cased as if they are considered headers, so this is inconsistent.*)
4. [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)  "...is automatically added to a **r**eopen queue for community review." (*An aside... is it ["the Reopen votes queue"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-reopen) or "a reopen queue"?*)
5. [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2,000 | access review queues | Access **f**irst posts and **l**ate answers review queues |

There are more, but I think that's enough to make my point that the way the style guide is being applied in the updated review queue articles is not intuitive or consistent with other pages. On top of that, it serves no purpose in terms of communicating information. Randomly capitalizing Words in the middle of a Sentence when they aren't proper nouns is annoying.

**A**nd I do und**e**rstand that **i**t's ann**o**ying to have yo**u**r orthography nitpicked. When you look **a**t that s**e**ntence and th**i**nk "What d**o**es it matter? I know exactly what that text means." consider that the reader probably doesn't know what yo**u**r style guide says; they just know what they typically see. Using unconvention**a**l styling for docum**e**ntation makes **i**t harder t**o** **u**nderstand.

Comment: There's a parse ambiguity with those nouns strung together anyway: "(low-quality posts) queue" vs "low-quality (posts queue)".   I guess we all know what it means, but I think "low-quality-posts queue" would be better.  I suppose this is all part of the gradual dropping of hyphens that's happening at present?

Comment: @TobySpeight Interpreting most English text requires context to resolve ambiguity; that’s what makes English so expressive and is part of its charm ;) Excessive punctuation can be just as troublesome as a lack of punctuation. What is far more important is consistency. Having a style guide is a great first step, but it needs to be explicit enough that writers can understand how to apply it to specific content.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The text in the closure banner explaining that there's a reopen review available for a question is unclear:

> An edit was submitted for review 59 mins ago.

An edit wasn't submitted for review, an edit was *made* and the *post* was submitted for review. Can this be change to reflect the correct meaning?

[image: Close banner with message "An edit was submitted for review 59 mins ago."]

Comment: Can you please link me to an example? In some instances there is an actual edit submitted for review (when it's a suggested edit), but in others you're right that the edited post was submitted for review. I want to make sure we're differentiating appropriately.

Comment: @kristinalustig https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982767/how-to-dynamically-load-a-file-from-a-select - As of comment time the post has had no suggested edits

Comment: Thank you! Looking into this.

Comment: I've updated the wording to reflect the fact that the post is what's being submitted. It likely won't be in until early next week, as it's Friday afternoon where I am, but I'll mark this as status-completed now since it's in-flight. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 7):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

There should be a **custom comment** option in the New answers and New questions queues because most of the time the default (i.e. the new "community bot" comments) comments do not pertain to the new answers or questions. For example, we also get new questions that should be on the Meta of the site but there is no option to let the OP know.

In answers, we also get answers that should be comments but there isn't any option.

Comment: P.S. I haven't read all the answers so if my answer is a duplicate, please do let me know.

Comment: Most of the time [new questions are also posted as answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/573899/365490).

Comment: The custom comment is there on "Add a comment" on the post, no? Why would we give users the power to post anything they want in a comment under the Community user?

Comment: @Unconsidered The main problem right now is that if you simply "Add a comment" you can't actually finish the review...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm hopeful that this will be changed to include an "I''m done" button. Lots of other Answers in this post has requested one. On an off-note to this: If an Answer should be removed, posting a comment isn't a sufficient action.

Comment: There's now an "Other action" option to allow ending the review after commenting, but it does still feel odd that you have to use that option instead of the "Share Feedback" one when you're still... *sharing feedback*.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

#### Inconsistent font size in the reopen review box.

Maybe it’s my phone’s fault (iOS Safari), but I reviewed a post for reopening and this is what I saw:

[image]

These should use the same font size.

Comment: Finally looking into this and I cannot repro it. Is this still happening for you? For now, I'm going to status-norepro.

Comment: @kristinalustig I'll let you know next reopen review I do.

Comment: @kristinalustig It is still happening for me, exactly as pictured in the post here.

Comment: @kristinalustig Still getting this.

Comment: @kristinalustig this can only be reproduced on an ios device.

Comment: A similar issue was reported as a separate post here: [Close reason text is badly sized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383639/335251). (Potentially also related: [Rotation makes dropdown text too big](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380401/335251))

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Add OP shading to the revisions summary in the Reopen queue**

In the Reopen queue, when summarizing the changes to the question, please highlight the owner of the question, using the standard highlighting already used for OP throughout each thread.

> [image]

This is good for consistency in terms of how information is presented elsewhere on the site, but here it is also a useful handle to be able to parse quickly what the edit history looks like. Was the question extensively edited by OP or by somebody else? This is an important piece of information and the design language already has the tools to communicate the answer effortlessly.

Comment: I implemented this today! It likely won't be pushed to production until early next week, as it's Friday afternoon where I am, but I'll mark this as status-completed now since it's in-flight. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @kristina Great to know!

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369126/562482) describes several issues regarding having the canned feedback appear as a comment from the *Community* account. Also, this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067/562482) asks to allow having those comments be flagged, this [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369080/562482) requests being able to undo accidental wrong feedback, and this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369050/562482) asks for an option to be able to (easily) delete anonymous comments.

In addition, [Zanna](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/322419/zanna)'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369050#comment1231470_369050) states:

> Please let me (as a mod) delete these comments!

and then further explains in this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369050#comment1231473_369050):

> Nope! I just get a notification saying the comment will be deleted automatically when the post gets fixed, ...

I don't recall where I read this, but it seems there's doubt about when & how it's determined that the "post gets fixed" so these comments are then deleted. Nonetheless, I believe that at least diamond moderators should be trusted to delete these comments.

The [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bot already does a lot of other things which, in my opinion at least, are not particularly closely related to this new use. I believe creating a new special bot, called something like "Review", to use instead would solve, or at least help mitigate, many of these issues, as well as allow more flexibility in any future added features. These benefits include:

- The new name would make it clearer to anybody reading the comments where they actually come from. I, even as a relatively knowledgeable user, found it confusing to see comments from the "community" when they are actually from specific users while in the review queue instead. This alternate name should also make it less likely that users think it's from a "moderator", as mentioned in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369126/562482).
- This should help reduce the chance that people think it's some automatically generated comment, e.g., from a computer algorithm (as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369126/562482)), instead of being from a site member during review.
- The display and behavior can be tailored for the "Review" comments so, for example, they can be modified and deleted by diamond moderators, flagged (as requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067/562482)), more easily deleted by regular members (as asked for [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369050/562482)), etc.
- With any other review related features added later that involve using a bot, then having a specific "Review" one available may more easily allow additional customizations and flexibility compared to using the "Community" bot instead.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There's a need for the canned responses to deal with one of the most common problems: [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/244695). I noticed on [this deleted SO NAA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69031536/2370483) that the canned comment was

> Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

That's fine and good, but it's too vague for the situation (and I could easily see users responding with "Well, all the details are in the link!"). I personally use this canned comment (offered for an example of what I'd like to see)

> A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

## First Answers Canned Responses Give Help Link to "How to Ask"

The help links in the First Answers queues incorrectly lead to the how to ask help page.

The links should lead to how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

[image: Picture of Share feedback popup problems outlined]

Below is an example of a posted canned response with the incorrect link after selecting **Answer needs supporting information**.

[image: Picture of Canned response problem outlined]

Answer (score 6):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Thank you for all the improvements.

Can you please remove the option to "leave feedback" by community user from "First questions review"? While this option makes sense in "Low quality answers" and in "New Answers review", having this option in "First questions review" is unnecessary. If I say that the question is unclear I expect that I cast a close vote on it and push it into the close review. I don't want a noisy comment from community user that states the same thing as the blue banner does. I can't even self-delete this comment. I would have to flag it and ask moderators to delete it.

Please replace that option with "close" option instead.

Comment: I disagree with this.  I think the point is to get feedback to users _before_ the question is closed, with the hope of the question getting fixed.  While it probably _should_ cast a close vote and push into close review, the comment would also be helpful.

Comment: Ideally there'd be an easy way to remove the comment if/when it's addressed, though.

Comment: Getting them feedback before it's closed is good, absolutely - that said, we shouldn't prevent you from voting to close the question without visiting it outside of review and closing it there.

Comment: @Catija How does the comment get deleted?

Comment: What comment are you talking about, @Unconsidered ?

Comment: @Catija One of the ones left by the Community user when choosing "Share feedback"

Comment: The blue banner disappears when the issue is addressed and the question is reopened. The new comment posted by community stays there forever to haunt you and remind you of your past mistakes.

Comment: We specifically are trying to send more proactive feedback to folks who are posting their first questions/answers. You can still cast a close vote on it.

Comment: @kristinalustig How can I cast a close vote from the review? Even if I cast the close vote in a new tab, I still have to take an action on this post to finish the review. If I chose to leave a comment, and OP edits the question, the comment will not go away.

Comment: Maybe the "community" comment could go away after some time or if the post is significantly edited or reopened.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The first questions and first answers review queues don't show up in red, even when there are tasks to review:

[image: review queue sidebar with a gray dot by first questions and first answers]

When I looked at it from the inspector, I noticed that the first questions queue has the HTML:

```html
<li class="-item danger-active">
    <a href="/review/first-questions" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 12, in_danger: false })">
        <span class="-title">First questions</span>
            <span class="v-visible-sr">(Active)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

As opposed to late answers:

```html
<li class="-item danger-urgent">
    <a href="/review/late-answers" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 5, in_danger: true })">
            <span class="-title">Late answers</span>
            <span class="v-visible-sr">(Urgent)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The

```html
<li class="-item danger-active">
```

and

```html
<li class="-item danger-urgent">
```

seems to be the culprit here.  `danger-active` doesn't have the proper styling, whereas `danger-urgent` does.  When I run:

```js
$(".danger-active").removeClass("danger-active").addClass("danger-urgent");
```

The issue is fixed.

[image: review queue sidebar with a red dot by first questions and first answers]

So it seems Stack Exchange is implementing a new class name, but forgot to add it to the others and add proper CSS styling.

Comment: I knew something didn't look right. It's likely that [the threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/348196) wasn't set properly (or at all). Currently, the First questions queue has 1.4 posts. The only other explanation is that the threshold is (intentionally) too high.

Comment: Actually, after re-reading the "How we adjust the thresholds" section of that post, this doesn't really seem like a bug. It looks like the new queues just aren't yet used for enough time to gather data. **Edit:** But shouldn't the default threshold be the fallback? I don't know. You might want to wait for confirmation from the staff.

Comment: [It's red on Anime.SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiUSB.png).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Definitely a bug, then.

Comment: @41686d6564 It appears the issue totally different: the threshold was set, but isn't being correctly rendered client-side.

Comment: We forgot to set the threshold settings for these queues. Will be done shortly.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[image]

As I said in the [product discovery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367243/571958), the wording for this button is problematic. Remember that this appears as part of an ***edit***, so most users will simply think they are submitting their edit for review, as they are used to.

It should indicate a lot clearer that you are editing the question, ***and*** expecting it to be reviewed for ***reopening***. As I previously suggested some reasonable alternatives are:

- Submit edit for question's reopen review
- Substantial Edit

Comment: Another suggestion: "Submit question for review"

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Getting extra review tasks:

[image]

I didn't see this mentioned in another answer or the original post, but please ping me if it is there and I'll ditch this. I've poked around the stats and I've noticed I'm not the only one. I figured it might be a mod thing or high-rep thing, but at least a couple of the other reviewers have lower rep than me, and none of them are mods (at least not on SE).

**Update:** Along the same lines, a banner telling me I have reached my limit, while the progress bar tells me I still have more to do if I wish.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this always the case when the amount of items in the queue exceeds a certain threshold?

Comment: @Luuklag, If that's something else that's been modified with this update, then this is the first I've ever seen it in any review queue. And even if that's the case, I think the messaging needs to be consistent. It's at a minimum confusing, at worst it's outright contradictory.

Comment: I've had this happen before.  What happens is that when the number of items in the queue exceeds a certain threshold, the daily review count increases from 20 to 40, but if the number drops back down, it goes back to 20.  So what happened is you reviewed 22 while there were enough review tasks and afterwords it became 20 again, leading the system to the confusing "22/20".

Comment: I figured this out, and am getting a fix in. Basically, we keep the dailyMaxReviews count and only update your current review count dynamically (we don't refresh the whole page between tasks). So this bug only happens if the queue size changes while you're reviewing. I updated the javascript to update both numbers for each task. The fix will be shipped in the next couple of days. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 6):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "First Posts" review queue is now retired, but what are the plans to make it disappear from:

- the Review dialog in the top bar
- the [main review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/)

On most sites, it has been cleared and will not get any new entries.

Comment: First posts will now disappear from any site where it has no outstanding items.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Can it not be moved to a "retired" section like is done on the badges page? There's a lot of history there, and at least for the next little while keeping it accessible would benefit us I think. I don't see the need to hide it away completely.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot please post that request as a separate item

Comment: @YaakovEllis Pretty much [already covered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369019/345161), I think.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

### Please add a close link to the question in the first answer queue.

Every now and then you come across a low quality answer in the First Answer queue, well just because the question was low quality to begin with. It would be great to have a direct option to cast a close vote on the question then and there, instead of having to navigate away to the question itself to be able to do that.

I already looked at the question to see if the answer is doing a job at answering the question at hand. If I then identify the question to be problematic it should be easy to handle that as well.

Answer (score 6):

#### Pointless request for more details (from Community) on "Me Too" NAA

FWIW, I came across this comment when it was in the Late Answers review queue on Ask Ubuntu.

As the screen shot shows, a totally inappropriate comment is left by community on a "Me Too" answer. There clearly aren't any more details available for a solution as the poster has the same issue as the OP and doesn't know how to solve it.

> [image: More details requested on a Me Too answer]

In addition, when I try to flag it as no longer required, in an effort to remove it, you get a message saying that it can not be removed and will be removed only when the issues have been addressed:

> [image: Can not flag erroneous message for removal]

**Note**: I wanted to flag it for removal because the intention of this "Need more info" comment is to prompt the new user to expand upon their pointless answer, thereby wasting their time working on an answer that will clearly be deleted in the near future.

---

This comment is obviously auto-generated somehow, but not by the Recommended deletion option in the **Late Answers** review - possibly/probably by some mechanism from another review queue (I don't know if it was generated in one of those two new First Questions/Answers review queues).

Comment: This is a First answers review comment.  A fix for my requests [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/165261) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369325/165261) would address this problem.

Comment: Yes, quite possibly. Maybe expand `rather than asking related questions, thanking other posters, or other commentary that does not answer the question.` to `rather than asking related questions, thanking other posters, "Me too" answers, or other commentary that does not answer the question.` to make it explicit. "Me too" is one of the most common NAA (along with thanks and questions as answers). I admit that there are two issues mixed into my post here: (1) The inappropriate comment, and (2) the indelibility of said inappropriate comment. They may be better separated into two different issues.

Comment: Good idea. I updated the language in my post (not with your exact phrasing, but the same general idea of explicitly including "me too" answers).

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When voting to close a question in the First Questions queue, actually having to flag because the close option isn't available(!), the review item hard refreshes. My vote to close, via flagging, was a binding vote as a mod so not sure if this happens when the close vote doesn't cause the question to be closed. This seems to be happening because of the review item hard refreshing not soft.

The resulting effect here is that the reviewer actually loses the review that they've just performed and can't complete it as the item that comes back is the invalidated review, due to the closure.

---

And side not, perhaps more importantly. Voting to close should really be an available option in First Questions. To be honest the idea behind these queues is good and this is a good start but we've lost way too much functionality from just plain old First Posts that things have gone back too many steps.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369117/398063

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

With the recent update, the other actions item will stay selected if you post a comment on a post, and then delete it, allowing you to complete the item without *technically* doing anything:

[image]

Probably very unlikely most people would do this, but it could be abused.

Comment: Technically, it posts a deleted comment which is visible to the moderators...

Comment: I came here to also report this.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369040/165261) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369035/165261) (both already marked completed), another blank/missing state: when there are no more posts in the queue (appears to affect all queues).

This also occurs when you have completed your reviews for the day, suggesting that the fix for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369040/165261) has since broken.

[image: Screenshot of the close votes queue with nothing below the filter button and daily reviews count]

Comment: Yep, just recreated in the Low Quality Answers queue as well...

Comment: [Already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369567).

Comment: @bad_coder Ah, good catch, I missed that.  I'll leave this up as a signpost for anyone who does the same as me and tries to report it here...

Comment: [Also reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369525/165261).

Comment: @RyanM the catch with these bug reports is they were posted separately for each queue because the lack of the message didn't happen in every queue, it was also fixed and regressed for some but not all queues.

Comment: I fixed this today! The fix likely won't go live until early next week, but I'm going to mark it as status-completed as it's in-flight already. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 6):

Similar reactions from the Low Quality Posts/Answers and Late Answers queues are not merged together (i.e. upvote existing comment instead of posting a new one) which leads to an unnecessary redundancy:

[image]

The first comment originated from the Low Quality Answers queue and the second, with the same type of deletion recommendation, from the Late Answers.

Answer (score 6):

(Possible) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The "Late answers" and new "Low quality answers" queues have very similar (in fact, almost identical) UIs. In particular, the canned comments available when selecting "Delete" or "Recommend deletion" are the same.

If a second reviewer in *one* of those queues selects a comment that is already present, then a new comment isn't added; rather, the 'original' comment is automatically upvoted.

However, when the *same comment* is added from the 'other' queue, it is added a second time, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69129597/10871073) (10k on SO required to see it, as it's already deleted). Should this also just upvote the existing comment?

---

Related: Do "Recommend deletion" votes from those two queues act cumulatively? That is, if (say) four such votes are required to kill the post, will one from "Late answers" and three from LQA finish the job?

---

Screenshot for those lacking 10k privileges:

[image]

Comment: Dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369618

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [How do I use the First answers queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) help page refers to "this question":

> One review from a user is enough to dismiss the task so review carefully to ensure that this question meets site expectations.

Comment: This was marked as fixed, but for whatever reason, it doesn't seem like this change was actually made. I've now fixed this part of the [How do I use the First answers queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-answers) Help Center article network-wide (along with a few other minor edits to the text).

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks for this modification.

Can you add multiple new options in "Share feedback" options such as "This is not an answer" (for people who are asking for help in an answer).

Also, when we add specific comment (and not premade one), we can't validate the review such as before.

Edit: Include in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#369017) and will be fixed (planned)

Comment: Wouldn't this be handled by flagging as NAA instead?

Comment: NNA ? There isn't option like that in first answer queue

Comment: And that is a bug that's already planned to be fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#369017

Comment: Oh ok, such as it doesn't mention exact issue, I think that was different.

Comment: NAA feedback is a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/165261)

Comment: This is fixed - you can flag answers as "Not an answer" now and then submit your review as "Other action."

Comment: Thanks you! That's perfect

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The canned comments do not include the *"From Review"* link, similar to the ones from the Low Quality Posts queue.

Example from Late Answers: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29721791
I chose the option for *"I'm having this problem, too"* and this is the comment that was automatically posted, without the "From Review" link.

A matching review from the Low Quality Posts - https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29725913 which includes the "From Review" link.

I'm not sure about the new First Q/A queues with the community feedback. Providing such link might be an anti-pattern for the anonymity purpose, but it should be there for the [planned regular feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues).

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The "Asked {x}" text in a review displays the question's age in a way that's different to how it's displayed when the question is viewed.

---

For instance:

| Review | Reported in review | Reported in post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29761095) | [image: "Asked today"] | [image: "asked 48 mins ago"] |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29755867) | [image: "Asked today"] | [image: "asked 19 hours ago"] |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29761598) | [image: "Asked 12 days ago"] | [image: "asked Aug 26, 7:27"] |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29759827) | [image: "Asked 3 months ago"] | [image: "asked May 28 8:30"] |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29761136) | [image: "Asked 11 years, 5 months ago"] | [image: "asked Apr 13 '10 at 8:03"] |

The precision for questions posted in the last 24 hours (just reported as "today" in review) is especially annoying because when doing some review tasks, the relative timing of a question and its answers can be important.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

A [review task in the first answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29759889) had multiple users review it:

[image: Two reviews on one review task]

Comment: Dupe with https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369545

Answer (score 4):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

> **Turn off the Help & improvement queue**

Can the company give badge stats of the H&I queue now that it's closing? (If the review statistics for the queue stop being visible it would also be good to have them posted.)

SEDE doesn't reveal for which queue badges were awarded. I think reviewers who were active on the queue would enjoy knowing the final breakdown.

Comment: It says _"**History** for and badges awarded from this queue will remain as they are."_, so maybe the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) will still be accessible but just removed from the front page? If that's the case, then I think no further action will be needed.

Comment: @41686d6564 the main point I asked about was how many steward/reviewer/custiodian badges were awarded for the queue. Then *"It will remain in the listing* **until** *its current items are exhausted"* so if the overall stats are removed I would like to see them published for reference.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
Related to [this other feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369041/398063).

Since the First Posts queue is retired, can the "How do I use the First posts queue?" link be removed from the Help center's general preview? It would still be accessible from the ["View more" link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues), but now there'd be no more "obsolete" info on a page that's frequently linked to, or looked at by, new users; which sounds slightly better in terms of UX.

It could be replaced in the general preview by a link to the Close votes queue help page; linking to First Questions without having its twin "First Answers" on the same page would seem unbalanced.

Comment: First Posts queue help center page has been replaced by First questions and First answers and no longer shows in the Help Center's general preview or the "View more" link.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Missing space between OP and OP's reputation**

At least in the Close queue, the UI now shows the OP and their reputation just below the title of the question. There is currently no space between the two, which looks pretty crowded.

> [image]

Comment: Reported in [User card is missing padding between username and reputation in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368899/user-card-is-missing-padding-between-username-and-reputation-in-review-queues). I'm not sure this is related to the new workflows and/or queues. It seems independent.

Comment: This is completed, though it is not related to the release being discussed in this post at all.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I just completed a few reviews now (close vote queue on TeX.SE using Firefox on Ubuntu) but the space was still missing. The post author line is right-aligned but otherwise it looked the same as in the screenshot above.

Comment: I'm still seeing this. Once though, my page refreshed and it seemed to be correct. Otherwise, the space always not there.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but FWIW I *hate* the new thingy. Too many steps, but mainly too locked-in to a hard-coded sequence of steps, with no turning back. *Bad* UI design, IMHO.

One simple example (and yes, similar to what some others have said): You must decide up front whether to OK a post or edit it.  Once you choose `Edit` you're done - no going back.  An `Edit` apparently implies `OK` after editing.  *No, it doesn't.*  You might want to skip or close or edit again or...

Why would you need to decide the ultimate fate before being able to try to improve the post?  We used to be able to edit, comment, save, wash, rinse, repeat,... whatever -- before deciding on a review fate.

That's just one tiny example.  This seems to have been designed by someone who's never used an editor.  Reviewing involves editorial actions.  The hard-coded flowchart here is horribly misguided, not to mention a time sink and a general bother.

*It wasn't broken.*  Shoudn'ta tried to fix it.  Or shoulda gotten a high-school intern to improve it.

But maybe the real aim was to get cut-and-dried metadata about reviews, rather than let humans use their brains. Multiple-choice on steroids, for automatic pigeon-holing? The result will be poorer quality reviews, and likely an abandonment of some reviewing.

Just one opinion.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Similar to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369035/295232) which has already been fixed: if you go to an open First Answers or First Questions review item in a private browser window, you don't see the ["Please log in to review First Answers" banner you'd see in e.g. Close Votes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPzNC.png), but an empty banner. Also, the post is grayed out.

[image]

Comment: Partial duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369059/349058

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Staff" label is not aligned with the user detail in the [review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79219).

[image]

Comment: This is a problem everywhere and was reported under the labels post as well. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367932/273494 @kristinalustig

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### *First Question* queue audit

On this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29682284). All I want to do is comment to ask for more details - more focused than the canned answers.

So I add a comment and then when I hit save, a box pops up, saying this is an audit. So there isn't any use for me to exit and a good way to find audits which is not good.

This is a more general issue. The share feedback button needs to give more options or allow us to enter a comment.

Answer (score 3):

> **Name change: Low quality posts → Low quality answers (Stack Overflow only)**
>
> This queue will continue to handle answers only.

Why only on Stack Overflow? In several discussions on the purpose of having low-quality reviews for questions (as opposed to close reviews), the only (reasonable) answer was that it makes sense on Stack Overflow due to its scale. Everywhere else, it only slows the process down since another step is needed to bring the question to the close queue. After all, closing (or improving) is all that can be done with low-quality questions anyway. Also see: [Why can questions be flagged but not closed for very low quality?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239688/255554)

With low-quality reviews for questions being gone on Stack Overflow, what reason is there to keep it at all?
So, **why not send all questions flagged or auto-flagged as low-quality to the close queue directly?**

Ceterum censeo: Remove the *very low quality* flag for questions (or altogether), since other flags already serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Adding "Edit and share feedback".

Say that you are reviewing a post that has too much code.  You can edit out the unnecessary code, but you also want to share feedback, so the user knows why you edited and hopefully won't make the same mistake again with future posts.  To do so, you would have to open the post in another tab, click "Share feedback", then edit it in the other tab.

Adding an this option would make situations like this a lot less cumbersome and would also encourage such behavior.

Comment: If you want to add a custom message explaining why you edited, there's an "Add a comment"-button (looks like a link) under the post, no?

Comment: @Unconsidered It wouldn't be from Community, you wouldn't have the canned responses, and most people probably wouldn't consider it without an option being present...

Comment: Yeah.. sticking one's head in the sand under the Community user isn't my idea of being a good member. There's also no way that a canned comment could possibly be specific enough. Putting in a comment as "This has been edited because it needed to be edited" is hardly helpful. I didn't try to edit one, but I'm expecting there's an edit summary to be filled out?

Comment: @Unconsidered "There's also no way that a canned comment could possibly be specific enough" - in my example scenario, there is: a post has too much code, you edit out the unnecessary code, then add the "too much code" comment.  "I didn't try to edit one, but I'm expecting there's a summary to be filled out?" - users (especially new ones) rarely read that.

Comment: I see. One canned comment for "Too much code". What about "Too much fluff"? Or "Not enough inline code", "Missing code block", "Grammar corrections", "Wrong tags", "Not enough line code and wrong tags", "Too much fluff and needed listing of items".. you see where this is headed, right? :) To account for all the scenarios, there's only the option of making it possible to make custom comments under the Community user..  and that is just ripe for abuse :/ So.. we're back to posting a comment as ourselves or using the edit summary.

Comment: The request is very similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369045/348196) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369116/348196).

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Missing share link

The `share` link *under* the post is missing:

> [image: Missing share link in First Questions]

There is only `follow` and `flag`. It was there previously in the first posts review and is same present in the late answers review:

> [image: Share link in Late answers]

Comment: The link to the Question is there in the post summary for the post you are reviewing. It links directly to the Question/Answer. However, they have removed all links in the tabs with the "Question" or "Other answer(s).." including the comment links :O

Comment: This was already reported in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369017/571958) and a comment by Kristina states that all links will be added

Comment: By the post summary, do you mean the title? That gives the long URL, but the short (share) URL is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the *First questions* queue, if there is a pending suggested edit on the post and you press the inline *edit* button after reviewing the suggested edit you are taken out of the *First questions* queue and find yourself in the *Suggested edits* queue.

Happened to me in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29731091).

Answer (score 3):

The "Flag" option is missing in the Low Quality Posts queue:

[image]

This option is important even in this queue since it may be necessary to flag for a moderator's attention (e.g., to remove PII, convert to a comment, notify the moderators that user(s) are being rude, etc.). Without this option I have to exit the review to raise the flag, but users should never need to exit the review in order to properly review it.

Frankly, I don't understand why any of these options are removed from the post in the review queue in the first place -- it's not like they take up a lot of space.

Answer (score 3):

The Reopen Votes queue lacks an option to add a comment to the post, edit it without reopening it, or flag it:

[image]

Several times I have wanted to add a free form comment to tell the querent why the post still isn't acceptable (perhaps the post had multiple issues and the querent only addressed one of them). Without an option to add a comment to the post, however, I have to exit the review to help the querent with a comment.

Similarly, there is no flag option. What if the querent added some rude text in frustration over the closure of the question, and I want to raise a flag to notify the moderators that they need to keep an eye on (and perhaps mod message) the user? To do that I again have to exit the review. And what if I want to edit out the rude text myself without voting to reopen -- again, I have to exit the review to do that.

Once [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369617/299342), I don't understand why the review queues are missing options normally visible on a post -- they don't take up much space but are sometimes needed.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I would like to see the [all queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) link somewhere (maybe at the top, next to the title, or like a button/tab) on each review page as a quick way to choose next queue where I can participate.

> [image: All queues]

Currently I have to use top bar, tap Review queue icon, then select "all queues" link.

Comment: Dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369565

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the First Questions & First Answers queues, the *Flag* and *Edit* post menu items are missing in from posts shown on the completed/ non-active review page:

[image: Non-active review page, with post shown that's missing the "Flag" and "Edit" options]

These options [were added back to posts that you're actively reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369017), but they're still missing in this case.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) - duplicate of [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889/284827)

The URL for the Stats or History for a review queue changes from `/review/{queue}/stats` or `/review/{queue}/history` to `/review/{queue}/taskID` once the page is loaded.

Clicking the refresh button then loads the review task rather than refreshing the stats/history page.

This seems to happen across all queues where I am able to perform more review tasks (i.e. where I've not hit the daily limit or where there are tasks available to perform).

Reproduced on { Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow }, tested on { Chrome 93.0 on Android 11, Chrome 93.0 on Windows 10, and Firefox 92.0 on Windows 10 }.

[image]

This also breaks navigation, e.g.:

- Navigate to History (the page ends up with the URL `/review/{queue}/taskID`)
- Click on a review task in my history
- Press back
- Instead of going back to my history, `/review/{queue}/taskID` is loaded instead.

Comment: Want to know the fun part? :) This is just a side effect of the queue attempting (and succeeding in doing so) to load another review when you go to "stats" and "history"... If you open devtools, you'll see a juicy error in the console because the code did not expect to be loaded on these tabs. I highly suspect this is an aftermath of fixing the bug with not being able to click on "learn more" in tabs other than "review tasks"

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Thank you for fixing the bug that [prevented the modals in the two new queues to be movable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369049/248627).

Unfortunately, the new "leave closed" modal seems to have the same problem:

[image: Trying unsuccessfully to move the "leave closed" modal]

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Review first answers

1. opened review queue
2. skipped few answers
3. found one non-answer
4. flagged it as being non-answer
5. **now what ?**

[image]

Comment: Already reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/348196) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037/348196).

Comment: @41686d6564 and still no feedback from SO team on any of them? Great Friday release folks!

Comment: ..now you've done your citizen work. You click Skip, you do not get an added review task for a progress to the badge-medal, but knowing you did your flagging, you can sleep well? :)

Comment: @Unconsidered And then another user gets that review task, until inevitably someone decides to click "Looks OK" for whatever reason...

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, or until it gets fixed. Why set yourself up for a review-ban if you can just wait it out?

Comment: @Unconsidered I'm not saying I'll do it, just that eventually someone is bound to.

Comment: @Anonymous So.. let them. The post has already been flagged. You can't prevent people from making wrong decisions.

Comment: @Unconsidered Say 1 in 20 reviewers click "Looks OK".  Normally a non-answer would have a 1 in 20 chance of being reviewed incorrectly, but with this change, it has a much higher chance.

Answer (score 2):

As a heads-up, since [Increase close and reopen vote weight for tag badge holders - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377950/increase-close-and-reopen-vote-weight-for-tag-badge-holders) has not been implemented yet, I'm still [on the strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented).
Moreover, there's no mention of if it was even considered.

[Reducing the amount of needed close/reopen votes from 5 to 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) was helpful, but this would reduce it even further -- since as was shown, the power of reviewers at SO is too inadequate for the workload for even that to fully compensate.

Answer (score 2):

I came across an answer in the First Answers queue to an off-topic question.  The question was asking about recommendations for software on Stack Overflow, and someone answered it.  What now?  The suggestions in Share Feedback hardly seem relevant; the answer is clear and doesn't need more information.  Is Looks OK the proper response to this?

Comment: Looks Ok is probably correct. If a question is off-topic but the answer is valid then generally it remains. The issue is with the question, *not* the answer. If the question is closed, then answer will remain, unless the question gets "roomba'd" - in which case both the question and the answer will disappear. You *may* find that some people downvote answers to off-topic questions as a way to discourage answers to questions that are off-topic, but I personally don't consider it a good practice. This doesn't seem to be a bug with the new review queues - it has always been like this, more or less

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

There is weird word wrapping on some queues for non-English sites, e.g. [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts):

> [image: Learn more word wrapping]

Answer (score 2):

The "Other Action" option is great!  I'm glad you added it.  However, I disagree with voting causing this to be selected for two reasons:

#### 1. When a post is upvoted, the reviewer should choose "Looks OK", not "Other Action"

If I choose looks OK and then upvote, the other action option is automatically selected, so I have to take another step and click "Looks OK" for the second time.  This seems to either discourage upvoting good posts or choosing "Looks OK" on good posts.

#### 2. Voting is separate from reviewing

A post can fundamentally be OK, but you can disagree with it (as is the case with most MSE posts, for example).  Voting is a personal opinion, not an alternative to reviewing.  By having voting select "Other action", voting becomes a review action.

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Thanks for the update! Regarding, the "Leave closed" option in the Reopen Review Queue, I'll repeat the feedback that I provided in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367231/changing-the-question-reopening-experience/367234#comment1223610_367234) to another post:

> If the question was put in the Reopen Review Queue *because of an edit*, the listed options should include a *"The edit did not resolve the original close reason"* option **and it should be checked by default**.

You've indeed added that option, which is great! Can we please have it checked by default though? I imagine that will be the option that is chosen in most cases and saving a click goes a long way :)

I know that there are good arguments against this but just to put it into perspective, in the old design of the Reopen Review Queue, one only needed to click **one button** to say that the question should remain closed:

[image]

Currently, it requires **4 clicks** just to communicate the fact that nothing substantial has changed about the question:

[image]

Comment: I think making the user pause to consider the reason might be helpful, though. It means the user has to affirmatively confirm they believe this is true (as opposed to being the "misc" reason). This means that if the user can't find an option that seems relevant, they don't have one chosen for them to help them proceed—it tells them they should reconsider recommending that it be left closed.

Comment: Presenting the options alone _is_ a motive for the user to pause and consider the reason. If someone is robo-reviewing, then having the first option unchecked will _not_ stop them.

Comment: My concern here isn't about robo-reviewing. My concern is about a user who thinks the question should be left closed, but on reflection—looking over the reasons because none is automatically selected and they _must_ affirmatively choose one—may find there's no specific reason it should be, change their mind, and act differently on the question.

Comment: I think having to make the choice manually is preferable. Having it pre-checked would also potentially mislead reviewers, e.g. "well the system already checked this one option for me, so I just accepted that was the right choice, and submitted the review!"

Comment: @TylerH I don't know. On one hand, that's a fair point but on the other hand, I don't like the fact that one needs to click `4 elements` just to communicate that nothing substantial has changed about the question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @41686d6564 I agree it is a longer process and could lead to fatigue, but the act of reviewing items itself is already a long process that you have to go out of your way to choose to do.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with TylerH here - prechecking a "default" when there is actually no default here could cause a bias towards a specific result, which isn't helpful for anyone. I'm going to status-declined this for now, but we'll revisit it in the future if necessary.

Comment: Agree with this. So many extra needless clicks.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Due to comments and downvotes, I want to make it clear: the following suggestion/request is based on the ***current*** implementation of things and assuming they stay that way. If there are going to be changes in the design of the queues that request might become obsolete.

---

In the **Late Answers** queue:

There is now both an ***action*** for edit (red square), and also the edit ***link*** under the answer (blue square):

[image]

***Please remove the one under the answer*** (blue square in the image) to avoid confusion (and be consistent with the new First Q/A queues). I accidentally pressed that in a review and when I finished editing I was thrown back to the original page and out of the queue. Of course I could go back and mark as Looks Ok but it is quite annoying and I'm pretty sure it is bound to happen to others.

Comment: Please no.. users need to be able to perform multiple actions, as in both flag and edit. The old "I'm done" worked very well for reviews where a user can (and should) perform multiple actions on a review.

Comment: @Unconsidered I'm not sure I understand if you support this or not (maybe you didn't understand my intention and I need to clarify). Users can still flag ***and*** edit. By flagging and then choosing the edit ***action***. What I am asking is to remove the edit ***link*** under the answer to avoid confusion. But as a side note, I don't understand why would you flag and edit. Makes more sense to flag and recommend deletion...

Comment: But then the user needs to do the things in a very specific order, which I'm not a fan of. There will always be a situation that will require both actions. Maybe even a flag, an edit and a recommend deletion. Say someone posted personal information in a "Not an Answer"

Comment: Then surely something need to change anyway. Right now, editing is either an action finishing the review or throwing you out of the queue altogether. Either options doesn't fit what you describe so a change is required either way (in my opinion just bring back the old "I'm Done" and that's it...)

Comment: @Unconsidered Anyway, again, as a side note, there is really no reason to flag/recommend deletion ***and*** edit. If something is spam/rude/NAA/requires mods there is really no reason to edit as it will probably be gone anyway

Comment: That edit link has always been there... I don't think it is a good idea to remove it. It is consistent with the general SE UI (i.e. "Share Edit Follow Flag"), and would cause confusion if removed. It is the edit link's *behaviour* that has changed in the new review queues - it used to throw you back to the review queue and not to the question/post page.

Comment: @Greenonline The difference is that an edit ***action*** was added to the review which is the one that should be used. If anything, removing the edit link is consistent with the other reviews. Anyway, this is most probably not even relevant because it seems there are bigger changes happening and probably the I'm Done button will be back in some form

Answer (score 1):

In the new version Late Answers, the **Recommend Deletion** radio button leads to a dialog that sort of repeats the flag link.

For example, *for a link only answer*, you can **both** use the flag link to flag NAA as one used to do (and then the answer would be shunted off to the Low Quality Posts queue),

> [image: Flag dialog - NAA selected]

**and**, in the new version of the Late Answers review, also click the Recommend Deletion radio button and then select "Link only answer (not spam)".

> [image: Recommend deletion dialog - Link only selected]

Why the duplication? This confusing UI leads to a poor UX.

I'm sure that it wasn't like this previously.

Comment: Does adding a comment auto-flag the post? Because if not, then one needs to perform both actions.

Comment: 'Recommend deletion' has always shown this dialog. It's entirely different from the flag button. a) Clicking 'Recommend deletion' actually votes to delete the answer. b) You can submit without selecting a reason. c) If you select a reason/comment, that comment gets posted on your behalf. None of that happens with the flag button.

Comment: @41686d6564 - I'm sure that it has changed. The recommend deletion option used to be in the Low Quality Posts review, not the late answers, didn't it..? Previously it was just "I'm Done", and "No action needed". The recommend deletion addition is new (to Late Answers), and hence the duplication.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't pay attention that you were talking about late answers. Anyway, the flag button also exists in the Low Quality Answers queue. So, the same "duplication" is there too. Maybe you want to rephrase your answer into a [feature-request] of some sort? E.g., do you suggest, removing the flag button? Restoring the old UI? And what about the LQA queue?

Comment: BTW, you can see how it used to look like in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369026/348196).

Comment: @41686d6564 - Ah, nice one. I was looking for a screenshot. I ended up referring to the **Late Answers and First Posts** section in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/280335) to [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/280335). Yes, I should probably rephrase it to be a feature request. As it stands I am merely pointing out the duplication of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

**Audit context expectations**

I'm not sure where this fits, so I'll just give my feedback here for historical purposes and we'll see where it goes. I just reviewed a first answer and clicked 'Edit' to fix up its issues:

[image]

Now what I *expect* is that when that post is shown here, that all of the glaring grammar issues are sorted out. After all I did 'pass' my audit because I wanted to edit the thing, right? I don't see any previous editing effort here in the Congrats banner. So just for certain, I go to the answer itself. It's exactly the same. [I fix it up](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68820499/revisions). I've passed three audits now following this scenario.

However this seems strange to me. I agree that an edit should count as a pass. You only make that action if you are paying attention to what you are doing, and that's a proactive curative thing to do. PASS. But, as choosing 'Looks OK' correlates with a relatively large number of upvotes, it feels like 'Edit' should correlate with a good solid previous edit that's cleaned the post up. I have no idea how to tie together this context though. In fact, it's impossible I think.

1. You can't predict what a future edit will really do.
2. A grammatical analysis of a post is process heavy, and on motley sites like these with very specialized syntax and formatting for each, such an analysis is almost certain to flag up perfectly appropriate grammar as incorrect.

We may just have to all agree that this is the best we can do. Sure makes for an odd workflow though.

Comment: "*choosing 'Looks Ok' correlates with a relatively large number of upvotes*" Huh? "Looks OK" just means it is OK. It doesn't necessitate that the answer have a high score (or any score). It's just that *audits* are chosen by the system automatically based on very limited (read: dumb) criteria: post score. Your suggestion seems to indicate we should find posts that have been edited for grammar, and then upvoted heavily after the edit, and then have the original version shown as the audit, and then it's only passed if someone clicks "Edit"... this seems way too contrived, and v difficult to do.

Comment: A person should not necessarily consider an answer "bad", especially in a queue, just because it has grammatical problems. While I agree that grammar and spelling are important, as long as the content is *understandable* enough to get the point/content across to readers, it doesn't matter if there are some typos, missing articles, etc. in terms of whether it is an "OK" answer.

Comment: @TylerH, I am familiar with the way the audits are chosen. I'm not really making any suggestion (though yours is as good as anything they've got now I suppose). I don't think there is really any way to 'fix' this, if that is even the correct word. I'm just pointing out that it's an odd correlation. Even with your idea, what if the edit only dealt with clarity, but not atrocious grammar, or vice versa?

Comment: @TylerH, I do agree that grammar and spelling do not a bad question/answer make. My normal workflow is: Edit (if needed) -> Review -> Next Task. I've come across many many good posts that only had grammar issues, and responded to them appropriately (editing, upvoting, passing the review). It just seems an odd workflow for an audit. And I'm not even sure I have a right to complain. One of my highest voted meta posts on the network is about how comments *shouldn't* fail an audit (and others argued should indeed pass it). So I may have helped influence this quirkiness myself indirectly.

Comment: the problem is that English (any natural language, really) is an art, not a science. It is *incredibly hard* to parse prose about some specific subject matter and determine, programmatically, if it makes sense or not... and in this case, it would need to just "make enough sense", not "make perfect sense", so raise the barrier some more). SO would need to implement something *at least* on par with the Microsoft Word Spelling and Grammar check system, which itself isn't even that good anymore once you get into technical subject matter like science or medicine (or programming).

Comment: I totally get you, unfortunately I think you're right in that what we have now is probably the best we are gonna get. Maybe it telling you "hey, this is an audit" when you try to Edit it, rather than telling you that you passed the audit (like it does when you try to comment).

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

**[This is now its own queston. Please direct any comments etc.... there.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372400/if-you-reach-your-vote-limit-you-also-reach-your-review-limit)**

If you reach your vote limit, you also reach your review limit! Don't know how active this thread is, and this is probably minor anyway.

[image]**Edit:** This is a bit more serious than I thought. I'm now locked out of the Late answers queue! If there is no response here in the next day or so. I'll make a separate post about this.

**Note:** I can still review the First Questions queue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this always been the case for the 'Late answers' and the deprecated 'First posts' queues: see '[Why does the review system disable the "First Posts" and "Late Answers" if I reached daily upvote limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149664)'.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, Then why can I still review First Questions? Is that the actual bug, that that's still allowed?

Comment: Oh! Yes, probably the bug here is that one is allowed to review First Questions even after exhausting one’s votes.

Comment: The OP has said, "We will be monitoring this post until Friday, September 10th. Report any further issues after September 10th as new questions on Meta." So, could you please post this bug report as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[image]

[I'm still worried](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367246/213575) about the wording here. Edits should attempt to fix all issues with the post. While yes, the close reason is one, remember that posts can be closed by multiple reasons, just one is shown. Wording here should be less about the specific close reason and more about following the site guidelines like the message for the reviewers say.

Comment: "Edits should attempt to fix all issues with the post" - No. Some changes to a post *must* be made by the posts author. I shouldn't have to wait for you to clarify what you are talking about before I can clean up your spelling, grammar, or language.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov this facility was specifically designed so that editors can do that assertion instead of the system presuming any edit is fixing all issues. That's what this feature is about.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @ThomasMarkov here - one can edit a post to the best of one's ability and it's still useful, even if it doesn't fully resolve the original close reasons.

Comment: @kristinalustig that's not what this is about. It's about what's expected of the editor. The close reason is not 1 reason, it can be multiple, but the UI doesn't show all of them. Editors would focus in addressing what the close reason says, instead of fixing issues of the post. [We've already discussed this before.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185983/213575) There are questions that have multiple issues, but the editor would just focus on one of them. Please, remember what's the objective of this feature: making sure that the quality of the post rises to an acceptable level.

Comment: In other words, Tomas is missing the point. The feedback [I gave before noted this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367246/213575): itemizing badness and sidelinging generating good, on topic, specific questions. Review it again.

Comment: Okay, after reviewing your other thoughts I understand this now. Going to follow up with Lisa (designer) and see what she thinks. Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

There is a typo in first question (answer) queue actions block:

> [image: Other action]

It should be "Other actions" or "Another action".

P.S. English isn't my native language.

Comment: I disagree. I see this as shorthand for "I took some other action". "Another action" would imply to me that choosing that option would open a menu with other actions to choose from, not just allow you to finish the review. "Other actions" forces a plural, which may not be correct. I think the wording is good as it is.

Comment: If there is an error at all in this wording then it could be "Other action(s)"

Comment: I agree with @Catija, although if I were going to nitpick, the list lacks parallelism which makes "Other action" seem like it doesn't fit. "No action needed / Edit / Add (or Share) feedback / Something else" would be how I would put it.

Comment: I typically edit (when necessary) before I even begin the actual review. So 'actions' could be correct. But in its singular form, it could be encompassing.