# So is my progress toward the Steward badge for First Posts queue just gone?

Tags: support, badges

I just noticed I had more review queues than usual:

[image]

Noticing "First answers" and "First questions" were now separate, I checked "First posts":

[image]

Slowly but surely, I was working toward the Steward badge with the First Posts queue:

[image]

So is this progress just completely erased?

Comment: Not sure if this should be closed as a duplicate but you might want to post it as an answer to the linked question: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)

Comment: I've posted this as an answer to the announcement thread [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369016/674198), not sure what to do with this question, I'll let someone else decide that.

Comment: I've just voted to close as a dupe and upvoted your answer there. I expect you're not the only person who's going to be concerned about this.

Comment: @Spevacus That seems agreeable to me.

Comment: Closing this question really doesn't help those who want to know the answer. The so-called duplicate doesn't seem to have the answer or, if it does, it's hard to find (and if the answer *is* there, why should we have read reams of text in order to find it?).

Comment: @LarsBosteen While I get your point, this is how recent changes are typically handled. An announcement post is made and immediate feedback goes on that post, including questions about the ramifications of those changes. If staff are going to respond to such feedback, it's best to keep it in one place.

Comment: I don't believe this should be closed because it seems that many people are asking for a feature that distributes the retired 'first post' into the new 'first question' and 'first answer'.  I'd like to see such a feature, even if the distribution is some arbitrary percentage.

Comment: I've posted a separate feature-request for this problem, please upvote it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369078/please-transfer-reviews-or-just-split-score-for-them-from-the-first-posts-q