# Please, transfer reviews (or just split score for them) from the "First posts" queue to new "First questions" and "First answers" queues

Tags: feature-request, review, badges, review-badges

*This is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369015/so-is-my-progress-toward-the-steward-badge-for-first-posts-queue-just-gone), it's a **feature request**!

**Please do not close it**, leave the possibility for the staff members to **answer** this question (and not to just comment one of the answers on [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release), because [comments are not for posting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment))!*

Along with many users of the **Stack Exchange** sites, I was shocked that all the progress in getting the not-yet-received signs for reviewing the **"First posts"** queue has now actually been canceled.

This may not be an unsolvable problem on more popular sites like **Stack Overflow**, but it actually kills years of effort on less popular sites, where the path from **"Custodian"** to **"Steward"** can take many years. For example, it took me almost three years of daily monitoring the queue on [rus.stackexchange.com](https://rus.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats) to make **921 reviews**. And now it's all gone? And it seems to me that I am not alone in this situation!

I understand that this task probably has a number of hidden obstacles to its solution, but if you just leave everything as it is, you will kill the long-standing hope of many and the motivation to continue further reviews.

After all, many people here are programmers. If you do not know how to overcome the problems with the splitting of the queue, ask the community, and we will be happy to provide you with all possible assistance. After all, helping is what we are here for (so, I hope, are you).

Comment: Already addressed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369016/165261), including staff responses.

Comment: @RyanM, in comments to one of the answers to this question, staff said that it is possible to create a separate feature-request for it.

Comment: If you're referring to [Yaakov's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369016#comment1231290_369016), that was asking for that answer to be reworded as a feature request, which [has been done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/369016/revisions).

Comment: @RyanM, but it's a very important thing for many, so please it will be a question, not an answer.

Comment: A staff member has already said "We'll give some thought to a solution and reply back to this post."  Why do we need another post?  There are lots of important issues raised in the answers there.  Some of them haven't even gotten staff responses.

Comment: @RyanM, to make it possible for staff members to write answers to it, not just the comments.

Comment: @RyanM The staff responses are in comments. [Comments are not for posting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with staff responding to things in that manner, and it has been done that way many dozens of times in past announcements of that type. We generally prefer to keep all things related to a major change in one place (in answers on that announcement) because it is easier to track.