# Review queue "First questions" does not show any message when reaching the maximum number of daily votes

Tags: support, status-completed, review

I know that this is not a serious problem, and I was very hesitant to report it or not. I am not sure if it only happens in Stack Overflow in Spanish which is where I am doing the reviews.

The problem is that when reaching the maximum number of daily reviews, normally a message is shown in which it is clarified that the maximum revision limit has already been reached and, depending on the time, the remaining time is shown to be able to carry out more revisions.

Well, this is not the case for the new review queue "First questions" and I'm not sure if the same thing happens for "First answers" since I have not reached the maximum number of reviews yet. It only shows an empty box without any text.

As you can see below:

[image]

And this is what it looks like in dark mode:

[image]

As I said at the beginning, I'm not sure if it happens only in Stack Overflow in Spanish.

Comment: This has [already been reported in an answer on the most recent review queues release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369040/622284) and has been fixed. The fix is going to be live sometime on Monday per a comment there from a Staff member.

Comment: @Spevacus This problem is from the the list of review queues page, so it's somewhat different than the answer you linked to which is for inside the First Answers review queue. While the other problem has likely been fixed, this one apparently has not. I just noticed that after hitting my daily limit of close votes on Math, I got basically the same empty blue box as the OP, e.g., see https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ZET.png, Note the HTML source is `<aside class="s-notice s-notice__info flex--item fl1" role="status" aria-hidden="false"></aside>`, i.e., it's empty. I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @Spevacus In my previous comment, the problem occurs when I hit my daily up/down vote limit instead of the close votes limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was closed as similar to this [related bug fix in our review queue workflows mega-thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369040/209031).

However, there were multiple root issues causing the empty blue box.  In this case, when you hit the daily up/down vote limit - we restrict reviewing First Answers, because one of the possible ways to handle a review is to upvote the post in question.

Should be all set now - fix heading to prod this afternoon.