# The "Review queues" page shows an empty blue box below the "First Answers" queue when the daily up/down vote limit is reached

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

When the daily up/down vote limit is reached, the "First answers" review queue becomes unavailable. However, on the [Review queues](https://math.stackexchange.com/review) page, the blue box which should state this is blank, e.g., as shown below from the Math SE site:

[image: Screenshot showing "Close votes" and "Late Answers" with appropriate messages, but not for "First answers"]

This is somewhat similar to [Review queue "First questions" does not show any message when reaching the maximum number of daily reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369120/562482), but that one deals with a problem with the "First questions" queue instead, and with it occurring when having reached the maximum number of daily reviews. Note this other question was closed as a duplicate of this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369040/562482), although this is somewhat different as it's for the "First answers" queue, like what this question is addressing, and its problem occurs when in that queue rather than on the Reviews page. Although that answer was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by [kristinalustig](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344828/kristinalustig), with an associated [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369040#comment1231497_369040) on Aug. 27, 2021 of

> I pushed this fix out today, so it will be live either today or Monday, depending on how confident we are to push to production on a Friday afternoon. :)

since my question is about the same queue, but on a different page, and the the linked question is about a different queue, I'm doubtful that other question's problem has been fixed.

Regarding my issue, that linked answer has an Aug. 27 [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369040#comment1231548_369040) from [Jeremy Caney](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/724530/jeremy-caney) which states:

> @kristinalustig: FYI: I assume this will be addressed by your fix, since it sounds like it's just a missing string token from e.g. a localization file, but this issue *also* appears on [the `/review` page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), where this message is similarly displayed below the appropriate review queue.

i.e., my issue was reported then. Also, there's a Sep. 22 [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369040#comment1235320_369040) from [V2Blast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/335251/v2blast) which says:

> @kristinalustig: Is this the same as [this similar bug on the main review queues page?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11757)

The linked Role-Playing Games meta post says it happens when "out of votes", so I assume it's referring to the daily up/down votes limit.

Although this issue has been reported previously, I assume the reason that it's not yet been fixed is not due to any particular challenge or difficulty. Instead, the issue is likely quite simple to fix, i.e., it's probably just due to something like a missing localization string as Jeremy suggested, so I hope the problem will be resolved relatively soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix is on its way to prod right now.  Incidentally, this was related to us splitting up FirstPosts into FirstAnswer and FirstQuestion buckets and grabbing the message based on that.