# Better way to provide feedback on announcement posts

Tags: feature-request, meta, feedback

I have started to use the new First Question and Answer queues and am finding issues with it.

The problem is finding out if the issue has already been reported.

The current way is to reply to the question announcing the new feature: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/136010)

But finding out is a problem. For example, I needed to see if not having a close button had been reported. Searching for "close" provides too many hits. In this case, because the question is so long.

I can think of two possible improvements

1. Provide a simple list of the headers of the answers (I suspect that this is too much work)
2. In this case it would have been easier if the announcement was one question (or even a blog post) and then reporting issues was a simple question Saying "Report issues on new queues here"

Comment: Have you tried searching with the `inquestion:this` operator? E.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A369013+close

Comment: No just browser search - I only want the current pages But it is better but non obvious

Comment: Click (?) for help, and if you click  to search there is help too. --- Searching for [`close button review`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=close%20button%20review) (using the Newest Tab) provides both questions and answers (which is helpful, to find Feedback styled answers on Announcement posts) - the default is the easiest way, and the most useful. --- Asking about "searching using your browser, EG: CRTL-F" is **off-topic** here. In that case you could have looked for "button" (and sorted through the results), or even "Share" to jump to each section.

Comment: Use google with 'site:' to search SE sites, which is not as pedantically literal/restrictive as the SE search.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For this particular announcement post, I just [posted a wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/348196) consisting of a list of all<sup>*</sup> the existing bug reports and feature requests.

[image]

Hopefully, this will make it easier for users to quickly find if their potential answer is a duplicate.

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### As to the more general case,...

Maybe the company should automate this process by having answer templates for announcement posts where the template would contain some metadata placeholders for users to fill and that metadata would be used to automatically populate a list of reported bugs and feature requests. The template could be something like this:

```
<!-- tag: e.g., bug, feature-request -->
<!-- excerpt: Summarize your request or bug report in <100 characters  -->
<!-- status: Filled by staff -->
```

Or (probably better) infer the metadata directly from the answer's content. In that case, the template could be something like:

```
[tag:bug] | [tag:feature-request] <-- choose one

### Summarize your request or bug report in <100 characters
```

Then, the populating script would look in the markdown for the following:

- `[tag:*]` - to categorize the type of the answer/report
- the first heading - to be used as an excerpt
- `[tag:status-*]` - to categorize based on the status

As Journeyman Geek [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1231674), it would be great if there's a way for staff (actually, mods too) to pin that answer. Accepting the answer could be used as a workaround but accepted answers [will be unpinned soon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410854/8967612) <s>and it's currently only pinned when sorting by vote</s>.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Sorry, if I missed any answers or messed up with the excerpt/link. The answer is Community wiki though, so anyone can improve it.</sub>

Comment: this seems like a good idea. Also might be worth getting staff to select a omnibus/index answer as a selected one pinning it to the top

Comment: There is a way for the answer to be pinned. At least there was because the black theme thread on SO had the index thread pinned to the top by staff.

Comment: @bad_coder AFAICT, that one was pinned by marking it as accepted (two days after it was posted). The linked answer is now also accepted and pinned. But once accepted answers are unpinned, this will be a problem. That's why I think it's a good idea to give mods and staff an option to pin certain answers (only on meta sites). I plan to write a separate FR about this later.

Comment: Doing this manually seems to be the defacto accepted way to do it. It works well...