# What does the blue dot in front of the review queues mean?

Tags: support, design, review

I noticed a new blue dot in front of some review queues. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They indicate that these are new queues. You will see as much if you hover over them for long enough to view the tooltip.

They will disappear after you finish your first review in the queue, or 60 days post-launch (whichever happens first).

Comment: You can only hover if you’re using a mouse. How do I hover over something in my tablet or phone? Would it really be that hard to use “New!” instead of inaccessible glyphs that you have to explain?

Comment: To add to @ColleenV's comment above, isn't removing the use of inaccessible glyphs largely the *exact* reason we just revamped mod badges?

Comment: It could just use the same `NEW` badge as in [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives), for the sake of consistency

Answer (score 13):

As in many cases on Stack Exchange, you can hover over things and get more information about them:

[image]

Yaakov Ellis says it will go away in 60 days; if you want it to go away earlier, all you have to do is perform a review in that queue, or skip an item. (It's not enough to just dismiss the guidance popup.)

Answer (score 5):

When they are ***really*** new queues they are so new that they've never been used.

The blue dot makes more sense in that case, though despite being *used* on some sites they are still "new" to some users; though the notification of purported newness is only retained for two months.

Here are a couple of unused queues:

> [image: New Review Queues, with blue dot and First Posts queue with new "Retired" notification badge]

<sub><sup>In the interim the queues [looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2XOF.png) - before some of the removed queues were deleted, and the ["First Posts" queue was marked as retired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369396/282094).</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

This is what the HTML reveals:

```html
<div class="s-activity-indicator flex--item mt6" title="The First questions queue is new">
  <div class="v-visible-sr"></div>
</div>
…
<div class="s-activity-indicator flex--item mt6" title="The First answers queue is new">
  <div class="v-visible-sr"></div>
</div>
```

These look to be the [Stacks activity indicators](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/activity-indicator) that have a tooltip which simply says that these two queues are *new*.

Related announcment: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/289905).

Comment: The linked thread says nothing about the blue dot as far as I can see (or if the blue dot will be kept around after launch).

Comment: @bad_coder I also didn’t have the time to read the announcement yet, but indeed, I also couldn’t find anything about the blue dots with a quick `Ctrl`+`F` search.