# Clarify why review badge progress doesn't appear to add up

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, badge-progress, review-badges

I was able to complete some "First Answers" reviews today. After completing three, I took a look to see my progress. It shows as follows:

[image: Badge progress indicators: 1 out of 1 for Custodian, 4 out of 250 for Reviewer, 7 out of 1000 for Steward]

The page says that I've reviewed 4 review tasks, but the badge progress for Steward somehow says 7. Per [Proposal for awarding credit towards First Questions/Answers badges based on First Posts activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir), this is because there are three questions being carried over from the former "First Posts" queue, and hovering over the "?" icon confirms this. But this view isn't clear at immediate glance.

Can we please have additional information put into the verbiage of the review queues to better spell out why these numbers do not match up, that isn't hidden behind a hover tooltip?

Comment: Did you maybe previously do any reviews in the old "first post" queue?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - I've got over 2k reviews in the old "First Post" queue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proposal for awarding credit towards First Questions/Answers badges based on First Posts activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir)

Comment: "*So for example: A user with 2,548 reviews in First posts will have been awarded two Steward badges for First posts. Since the second badge was awarded, they reviewed another 250 for questions and 298 for answers — these are the carryover numbers. So they will then earn their first Steward badge for First questions after they review 750 items, and for First answers when they review 702 items.*"

Comment: @WaiHaLee - No, I don't think it does. If this were the case, there would be equal numbers on both the "Reviewer" and "Steward" badges, which is what I'm suggesting is wrong.

Comment: The wording on the other question isn't that clear, but from my reading of it, you got 2k First Posts reviews - following which you then performed 3 First Posts reviews on answers and N First Posts reviews on questions. Those 3 reviews count towards the new First Answers Steward progress, and the N reviews count towards the First Questions Steward progress.

Comment: @WaiHaLee - It should *also* count toward the "Reviewer" badge.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No, it shouldn't. As specified in the linked post, progress *only* counts towards one of the badges. Reviewer if you did less than 250 FP reviews, and Steward otherwise

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - The numbers should be equal. If it counts towards one, it should count towards the other. It's the way its always been. These are accumulative numbers, meaning, you can't get Steward until you get the Reviewer badge.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You can now, because of the "recalculation"/credit awarded for the retired First Posts queue. From the linked post: "If you have already earned [Reviewer] for First posts, then no credit for reviews over 250 will be transferred to FQ/FA" and "This does mean that if a user has reviewed more than 250 items in First posts, they will not get any credit to the Reviewer badge, but they will get credit towards the Steward badge in FQ/FA"

Comment: @everyone (me in several hours)  If the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/282094) needs an edit please do so.

Comment: I do see a valid feature request here, to make this indication a lot clearer so that it doesn't cause confusion. You can post that as a new request, or edit this one and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Related: *[Improving the Review Queues - Project overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901)* and *[Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)* (2021-08-26)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog - Per your request. If you'd like additional verbiage to re-open, please let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The verbiage is already provided if you hover over the badge progress bar or click on the question mark icon. We aren't going to be adding further customizations to this. If there are concrete suggestions on how to make the text of either of these elements more clear, we can consider this. But we are not going to be adding any new explanatory elements to the page.

Comment: The question asks for text to be added *that isn't hidden behind a hover tooltip*. Is this covered by your last sentence here?

Comment: Also, is there a chance that this can be reconsidered later if there are too many people who ask this same question on the meta sites and we have to repeatedly point them to the hover popup or your post, as if that's so, then it's probably confusing to have it show in the current way?

Comment: @sonic yes, that is what I status-declined. Things can always change later, if they're is enough of a reason to.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is really worth adding more text on this page for.

It's something that you only need to discover *once*, and the icon seems pretty clear that it's what you should mouse over for questions about the numbers (that is, if, as you say, it "isn't clear at immediate glance").  Once you do that, it has served its purpose, and it just exists if you need to check the number again.  Adding always-visible text would largely add noise to the page, as well as complicate the layout.