# Review queue totals showing incorrect values?

Tags: bug, review, badges

It appears that the review queue totals are incorrect for the First Answer and First Question queues.
[image: first answers]
The total for the badges is just one, while in reality I have completed 5 reviews in this category. Yet the total only shows one review. (It does not add the 4 tasks from First posts into the total.)
[image: First questions]
Here, the 22 tasks are not added to the total.

This is likely status-by-design, but as the previous reviews still count toward the badge totals (and thus the total reviews completed), I believe the totals should be revised to reflect the total number of reviews completed. (Instead of a misleading number of reviews that only happened after the site changed the review system.)

Comment: For me carry over is adding up on the sites where I have it. Related [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369396).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> while in reality I have completed 5 reviews in this category.

No, you've completed just one review in that category. The four (or 22 in the second example) were in a *different* category, namely First Posts. They just happen to count for your badge progress. Your proposed solution would work in your case, but not if you have more reviews:

[image]

I'm carrying over 11 First Posts (from 1,011 reviews), but they do not count towards the Reviewer badge because I already earned that one in the old queue (Steward as well, but those can be awarded multiple times). In your proposal, showing 51 there would be rather confusing in combination with the 40/250 progress for the Reviewer badge.