# Progress towards both Reviewer and Steward?

Tags: bug, review, badges

Looking at my progress in the First Answers queue on Super User, it shows a progress of 201/250 for the reviewer badge, but 248/1000 for the Steward badge. I'm guessing at least one of these figures is wrong?

[image]

Comment: It seems that this is caused by the migration of the former *First posts* queue to the new queues that replaced it, which are separate for questions and answers. That calculation is detailed in [this answer](/a/188732/) to our FAQ [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for). You can still manually access your past history in the old queue by going to `/review/first-posts/stats`, so check there to see if it adds up.

Comment: The question mark is a link to "learn more": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proposal for awarding credit towards First Questions/Answers badges based on First Posts activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir)