# Can we get inline question tools for the First Questions queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

Currently, the review "First Questions" only has the Follow and Flag options, plus Edit in the context menu for the queue. However, a typical question UI outside of this review also has the Close feature. Previously, the First Posts queue included this option, and now it has been removed from the First Questions. This means that users who are reviewing questions that need to be closed have to click Looks Ok, submit, go back to that post, and vote to close. Can we have the Close functionality added to the First Questions queue?

Comment: Yes, staff promised so: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#comment1231489_369017