# "This queue has been cleared" message is no longer being displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Ordinarily, when a review queue is emptied, a "This queue has been cleared!" message will appear, instructing the user to navigate to the other queues if they wished to continue reviewing.

Recently, though, I've noticed that all I see is a blank space (taken from Meta SE's [currently empty suggested edits queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits)):

[image: Picture of an empty page when viewing a review queue that's empty]

I also receive a console error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () /posts/undefined/votes?_=1631039719216

This problem applies to all review queues that I have access to across the network. It also seems to happen when trying to display the message received when you hit your daily review limit.

It seems a recent change has caused this problem. Could this be fixed?

Comment: I get this sometimes when the queue is not clear. Then I refresh.

Comment: @Unconsidered - hence the desire to have a positive affirmation that the queue is actually empty. Several times now I've stared at the blank screen waiting for something to load...

Comment: If the queue is cleared I would expect to see a link to the all the queues page.

Comment: Interestingly when following a link to an active review task, the message *does* appear: [Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality answers today; come back in 8 hours to continue reviewing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abekI.png)

Comment: FYI: This was subsequently [reported by @Ryan-M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369614/724530) on the Review Queue Workflows thread, and is being tracked as a [tag:bug]. You may want to upvote it there as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed this today. The problem was that we were mistakenly returning `null` instead of a partial `EmptyTask.cshtml` due (I think) to a refactor gone awry. Since it's Friday afternoon here, this won't be shipped until early next week, but I'll mark it as status-completed because the work is done and it's on its way. Thank you for reporting!

(I also fixed the unrelated console error! We were trying to get votes for the current post id, which obviously doesn't exist on an empty task.)

Comment: But the bug still exists in my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ELvU.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCBxe.png

Comment: This also affected my browser @JitendraSingh but has been fixed in the past few minutes; it was still broken a half hour ago.

Comment: Yup now it is fixed. Thanks @Rob