# No more thanks for reviewing 20 posts from a review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Since yesterday (at least) I stopped getting a message saying something like

> Thank you for reviewing 20 […] today; come back in […] hours to continue reviewing.

after 20 reviews from a review queue. What happens after the 20<sup>th</sup> review is that the review queue looks like any other review queue when there are no more reviews to be made; see the picture below. I don't know whether this was done on purpose or it is a bug. It would be nice if that message would return.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is a duplicate of this one - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369525/this-queue-has-been-cleared-message-is-no-longer-being-displayed ?

Comment: No, it is not. I am not talking about when there are no more reviews to be made. I am talking about a message telleing the user that, since they have made 20 review from a review queue, then they must wait until the next day before being able to do more.

Comment: Ah. Thanks! :D Looks like a general "Where have all the messages gone" investigation is in order. :)

Comment: Indeed it does!

Comment: I mentioned that in the most recent edit to my report that Catija linked but I did not elaborate in the same manner that this report does.

Comment: I've added a link to this post in the internal ticket for the other question - hopefully we can address both at the same time. :)

Comment: @Catija check carefully Nick's bag, he might have taken all the messages as souvenirs from his time working here. :P

Comment: The other question was edited to say "*It also seems to happen when trying to display the message received when you hit your daily review limit.*"

Comment: This had been fixed in some queues (like *First questions*) and had regressed yesterday. Reading the original anouncement post it had not been reported for the close vote queue (only for *First questions* - solved and regressed, and *First answers* - not marked as solved yet).

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Mobile: Edit review queue, after 40/40 daily reviews, does not list time to next review any longer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411392/4642212).

Comment: Reviewing is now *officially* a thankless task?

Comment: @AdrianMole It looks so. 

Comment: On a related, more positive note, for those queues for which the blue "Thank-you..." banner is displayed (the two new ones), the number of reviews shown is what you *actually* did. So, if you get to (say) 33 in a busy queue, then that queue drops below the "extend" limit, that number is maintained (both in the immediate message and in the "summary" page).

Comment: FYI: This was subsequently [reported by @Ryan-M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369614/724530) on the Review Queue Workflows thread, and is being tracked as a [tag:bug]. You may want to upvote it there as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I just mentioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369525/this-queue-has-been-cleared-message-is-no-longer-being-displayed/369966#369966), I fixed this today. The problem was that we were mistakenly returning `null` instead of a partial `EmptyTask.cshtml` due (I think) to a refactor gone awry. Since it's Friday afternoon here, this won't be shipped until early next week, but I'll mark it as status-completed because the work is done and it's on its way. Thank you for reporting!

Comment: It is working again. Thank you.