# First posts and Help & improvement review queues say you need 2147.5 million rep to review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface

Now that the 'First posts' and 'Help & improvement' review queues [have been retired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/284827), they don't appear in the list of the review queues in the top bar, nor do they appear in the [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page.

However, the pages are still active via [/review/first-posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/) and [/review/helper](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/) respectively - presumably to allow users to see their stats on them (my links point to Stack Overflow's review pages, but the behaviour is the same on all<sup>*</sup> Stack Exchange sites).

On the pages, instead of a notice saying that the queues have been retired, there is a confusing message:

> [image: You need at least 2147.5m reputation to review first posts.]

> [image: You need at least 2147.5m reputation to review and edit questions.]

Reputation [is stored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/284827) as a signed 32 bit integer, so presumably the *exact* required reputation is 2^31 - 1 == [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647).

Instead of having the message says that I need 2147.5m reputation, perhaps the message should say, e.g.

> This review queue has been retired.

or something similar - in addition to having the "Retired" indicator next to the review queue's name.

---

<sup>*</sup> Based on a sample size of 3 sites: Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, and Super User.

Comment: If this wasn't intentional I'll throw my waffles in the bin.  Works fine on AU.

Comment: @Ollie - By AU do you mean [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)? If so, when you say "Works fine on AU" do you mean you don't see that message (I do [1](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts), [2](https://askubuntu.com/review/helper))?

Comment: It's just broken itself.  It did work OK, but now...

Comment: Even Jon Skeet won't be able to review retired queues.

Comment: @Ollie Jon Skeet sees version of the page that uses 16 bit int

Comment: I wonder what will happen when somebody reaches that amount of reputation and vists those pages…

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica They will see a ticket to a month's worth of [free waffles.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/free-waffles)

Comment: Just remove that element all together. The retired label on top should be sufficient.

Comment: @Luuklag - I did consider that, but the emptiness would itself be [noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369525/284827) - in any other queue there's *always* something there, be it a review item, a message saying you've hit your daily limit, that there are no items to review, etc.

Comment: Have you tried getting that much reputation and seeing if you can review in those queues?

Comment: @RyanM You need 6-8 decades of work in order to be able to review those queues.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Then there'd better be some cool stuff behind the requirement.  Even more than waffles.

Comment: @Ollie legend says the first person to review a post in one of those queues will be gifted an unicorn.

Comment: @EkadhSingh That's _extremely_ unlikely. You need either thousands of years or some sort of inflation for that to happen. But if it did, I would expect SE to have switched to 64-bit integers a long time before that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We've just applied a fix for this issue! Basically when a queue was retired, it no longer had a Minimum Reputation set, by default (as greatly pointed out by you!) we set them to `int.MaxValue` for security reasons.

To fix it, now the "retired status validation" takes precedence over the "minimum reputation validation", and the queue will be displayed as Retired.

Thanks for reporting! We really appreciate the help.

Comment: So because that's the `MaxValue`, in theory, Jon Skeet can only get 2147.5 million reputation before it caps?

Comment: @Ollie for now you are absolutely correct! With that said, as soon as someone looks like they are getting there, we will most likely put a change in the roadmap to upgrade all the storage size pipeline.