# Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-stats, review-history

When I go to a review queue's stats or history, the URL is changed to a post that I didn't review yet. Even though this doesn't redirect me to the item's review page, it gets in the way of some navigation flows, like History -> some review -> Go Back, which actually redirects me to a review, not to History page.

In the GIF below I navigate to History and Stats page, see the URL being changed and then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the review item. The GIF only shows navigation from `/review` page, but it also happens if you are navigating through the tab links (Reviews tasks | Stats | History).

[image: Clicking on a review queue History or Stats will change the URL to a review item]

---

It happens to me in all queues that I have access and that aren't empty. I tested on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) - I can't test it here in MSE because I don't have enough rep.

Reproduced on Chrome, Opera GX, Brave and Firefox.

Comment: This also happens on Stack Overflow. It's very frustrating to have to click on the tab/button instead of being able to refresh the page.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Review stats and history pages URL update to a new review item](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411852/8839059)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed; the userID is no longer incorrectly substituted in the URL. So now clicking a review queue, its stats or history, correctly constructs the URLs (for example for the Close votes review queue) as:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close`

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats`

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history`