# Suggested edit review tasks are always trying to find the voting element

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

When I load a suggested edit task that is a tag wiki (including excerpts), I always get this error in the console:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: votesCast is not defined
    at Object.u [as success] (full.en.js?v=9dbde3c48422:9)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

It occurs both on active and [old review tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29623177).

Due to [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369889/navigating-to-review-stats-and-history-causes-the-url-to-change-to-a-specific), the error is now also present when going to any review stat or history page, for example

- [Suggested edits "Stats" page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)
- [Triage "History" page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history)

I expect this error presents itself network wide.

Comment: @bobble I'm a little confused about the tags. This problem occurs on all queues and not just suggested edits on tag wikis.

Comment: Oh, I though that it was just suggested edits queues, and the bug would only really be a bug if it was trying to access voting stuff that didn't exist, such as in tag wiki edits.

Comment: @bobble that was true.. until the other bug turned up :) So now you also get it on all review queue stats and history pages. Of course you could argue that once the other bug is fixed, this will only show for tag wiki edits again.

Comment: Feel free to adjust the tags to your liking.

Comment: I'm fine leaving them as is. I only hope that the other bug is fixed soon ;)