# When choosing to leave closed for the duplicate reason in the reopen review queue, allow specifying another duplicate target

Tags: feature-request, review, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

Sometimes, I encounter questions in the reopen queue which are closed as duplicates, but for which I disagree with the current duplicate target(s) and think a different one is better applicable/has a better answer. I also sometimes encounter questions that are closed for a non-duplicate reason, and disagree that it's a bad fit for the site but the question has already been asked and answered before (or it was a bad fit when asked but edited to fit within site rules, but has already been addressed before).

In these cases, the [guidelines for reviewing under the previous system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/180450/21) state that I should either leave closed and ping a gold-badge user to change the duplicate target in the former case, or vote to reopen and then re-close the question as a duplicate in the latter case. Thankfully, it's no longer necessary to resort to these fairly roundabout methods, as the current option to leave closed allows specifying a different close reason, including that the question is a duplicate.

However, when selecting that option, there's no way to specify the target. Once the question completes review, the close notice will simply indicate that others reviewed it as a duplicate. In the latter case, though, there won't be a link to any target which would leave the author and other users confused about which question this question duplicates. In the former case, the message implies that the reviewers thought that the same question is still applicable or still answers the question, even though the current target may not and another one is better.

When choosing the duplicate reason in the leave closed options dialog, can that please provide the option to specify a duplicate target, or explicitly indicate that the same target is still applicable?

---

The [review queue announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) states that it won't be monitored for answers after September 10 and requests filed later should be posted as new questions.

Comment: I can't even see the original duplicate target(s) in the reopen queue without opening the question in another tab. I think the duplicate workflow needs improvement.

Comment: I would suggest that this should also be the case for questions not originally closed as duplicates, particularly for unclear questions that become edited into duplicates.

Comment: @Sandejo Yes, this question applies to all such cases. I mention this in the second sentence at the top.