# Make comments left after selecting "recommend deletion" in the late-answers queue anonymous

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, community-user, late-answers

I checked [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/778756) and didn't find this mentioned (and I couldn't find it in search), so I'm asking it as a new question.

When leaving feedback on a question in the first questions queue, it appears as an anonymous comment from the Community user.

I assumed this would also be the case for leaving a comment after selecting "recommend deletion" in the late answers queue. But, after completing [this review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/1669787) and choosing to leave a comment from the list, I found that it wasn't from the Community user, rather, it had my name.

I don't remember whether or not it said the comment will be anonymous (I'm waiting for another one to appear in the queue so I can check, but it might take a while), so I don't know if this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but even if it doesn't say that, I think these comments should be anonymous just like the ones left from leaving feedback in the first questions queue.

Comment: Just to clarify: you mean the low quality queue, not late answers, right? As far as I'm aware, that's the only queue where comments show up with author names rather than from Community.

Comment: @Sonic I don't have access to the low quality queue yet. If you check the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/1669787) to my review, it was from late answers.