# Leaving a question closed as a duplicate in the reopen queue doesn't actually show the duplicate

Tags: feature-request, review, close-dialog, duplicate-suggestions

Since the [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/571958):

> If a Reopen votes reviewer elects to leave a question closed, the
> reviewer will be presented with a “Leave closed reason” modal (similar
> to the close reason modal) that will return feedback to the editors

One of the options is a duplicate. The problem is that you are not actually asked to choose a duplicate (like you do when flagging/voting to close). So today I stumbled on this in a question:

[image: A close notice of a question closed as needs details or clarity and a "failed to reopen" message with duplicate as the reason]

Which in general makes sense: the question was initially closed as needs details or clarity, I edited it to clarify and format properly, and now when it was clear it is apparently a duplicate (I did look for one and couldn't find).

**But the problem** is that there is no link to any proposed duplicate!

So my feature request is that when leaving closed as a duplicate in the reopen queue, you should be asked to actually ***provide a duplicate*** (similar to flagging/closing) and for the duplicate link(s) to appear either in the revised close notice or at the very least as (a) *"Does this answer your question?"* comment(s).