# If I've already left a comment in review, the system doesn't need to suggest an automated comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, review

I couldn't see this suggested elsewhere, but if I leave a comment during review, I don't need an automated comment suggested to me.

If the option to leave a comment has some other purpose (moves it to a different queue?) could that be separated out?

I also didn't see anything on [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) and I'm wondering it thats too old to add to now?