# Please reinstate flag option in low quality review queue

Tags: feature-request, flags, review-audits

In the Low Quality review queue we need a flag option. (Which we used to have not so long ago).

[image]

A simple example which would have been best as a comment, instead I'd need to leave the review queue, open the post separately in order to flag it, the same goes for rudeness or anything requiring a mod's attention. It's a nice idea to think that we don't need this option but there are enough inexperienced users who flag not quite the right way.

Request: Users should not need to interrupt their workflow, but should be able to raise the appropriate flag from review. Please instate a "flag" option in the low quality review queue.

Comment: This makes total sense for posts which need to be mod-flagged, there's definitely a need for that. That said, is the reason this doesn't already exist point to the idea that these posts should just be reviewed as "Recommend deletion"/ "Delete"?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not really sure about the knock-on effects on bans and the like, but they used to be there until the time the responsive-interface was under-way after the demise of the mobile app. I suspect the decision was to do with slimming-down the webpage. There's been [other functionality that's gone by the wayside](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) too. I thought I'd add this for consideration. @zcoop98

Comment: Also worth adding: [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369617) on the review queues final release post asks for this same feature.

Comment: Ahh, I'd missed that. I'm now debating if I should close this one as a dupe, but I'd still like SE to see it. What do you reckon? Do you mean add as in edit it into the Q? @zcoop98