# Reasons shown for "remain closed" votes in the Reopen Votes review queue should be listed in the same order as reasons in Close dialog

Tags: feature-request, review, close-reasons, vote-to-reopen

Since the [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/295232), when voting to leave a question closed in the Reopen Votes review queue, you have to select an option why it should remain closed:

[image: "Why should this question remain closed?" dialog box, with the following choices as radio buttons: "Original close reason(s) were not resolved.", "It asks too many questions at once.", "It lacks detail and needs more information.", "It is likely to be answered by opinion rather than fact and citations.", "This question has been answered, is not unique, and doesn't differentiate itself from another question.", and "This question doesn't meet a Super User guideline."]

These correspond to the following close reasons:

1. (n/a)
2. Needs more focus
3. Needs details or clarity
4. Opinion-based
5. Duplicate
6. A community-specific reason

Can these be reordered so that they match the order they appear in the Close dialog? I.e.

1. (n/a)
2. Duplicate
3. A community-specific reason
4. Needs details or clarity
5. Needs more focus
6. Opinion-based

[image]