# Help page for first question review is treating questions as answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, help-center, wording

I took a look at the help page for the new [first question review (Using Security.SE as an example)](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-questions) and it says:

> Share feedback if the post has the potential of being a good **answer**, but cannot be improved by anyone but the post-author. Choose from the standardized responses or leave a custom comment.

Notice it says "answer" and not "question". It should really be:

> Share feedback if the post has the potential of being a good **question**, but cannot be improved by anyone but the post-author. Choose from the standardized responses or leave a custom comment.

Am I correct? I request a fix.

Comment: It's been reported https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369694 but doesn't have a [status-*] tag added to it yet.

Comment: @cigien If I understand correctly the staff stopped monitoring those post after a certain amount of time. I think...

Comment: Hmm, the question says to post reports only up to Sep 10th. I *thought* I had done it on time, but it seems the answer was posted on the 11th. Either way, given that it has no response on it from staff, I see no harm in posting this as a separate question. I just thought I'd link to the previous report anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you are correct.

I've now fixed this part of the [How do I use the First questions queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-questions) Help Center article network-wide (along with a few other minor edits to the text).