# Rotation makes dropdown text too big

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, mobile-chrome, font-size

Using iOS Safari or Chrome, I noticed the font size gets increased dramatically in almost every top bar dropdown after rotating the phone back to portrait. The left sidebar menu is not affected, but even the mod diamond dropdown is.

I took screenshots with the communities dropdown.

Normal size (portrait — how it should look):

[image: shows 6 communities]

Too big (opened in portrait, switched to landscape and back):

[image: shows 5 communities]

Really? (Opened in landscape and switched to portrait):

[image: shows 4 communities]

Comment: Doubt it's something on SE side, but since I don't really know, not voting on the question. Hopefully, even in not directly on SE side, they can add some CSS to prevent it.

Comment: No repro on chrome andriod sadly,let's see if any IOS users can solve this