# Close reason text is badly sized

Tags: bug, close-dialog

I happened to have my phone sideways when I cast a close vote and noticed that half the close reasons are of a different text size. This is not the case in portrait mode. Reproduced for testing on both SO and Server Fault so presumably it’s network-wide.

> [image: screenshot displaying the described problem]

Similar inconsistencies show up in the community specific reasons as well:

> [image: screenshot displaying the described problem]

(Click through to see full-size pictures.)

---

This is on an iPhone 11 Pro; I hooked up my phone to my MacBook to use Safari's remote DOM inspector. The HTML and CSS for both items appears identical, including the `font` rules:

```css
font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI Adjusted","Segoe UI","Liberation Sans",sans-serif;
```

But for some reason, checking the font tab shows the regular sized text is rendering in ".AppleSystemUIFont" while the large text uses ".SF UI".

Comment: Perhaps related: [Rotation makes dropdown text too big](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380401)

Comment: This isn’t triggered by a rotation, and isn’t persistent – it does go back to normal after changing orientation. But yes it may be a similar root cause. I’m also using safari on an iPhone.

Comment: It's something with the device itself, most likely some font weirdness, doubt SE can do anything about it.

Comment: I had [the same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369183/674198) marked status no repro last year.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard this isn't some janky hacked up android phone. I literally cannot change the fonts in my web browser in any way.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Were you also on an iOS device when you experienced that? If so, please know that it'd be super helpful if you'd include that info in the bug report so that we can investigate more directly.

Comment: @Catija Just mentioned it in my answer there, it is on iOS Safari.