# On some sites the "Leave Closed Reasons" dialog is missing the second page, for reasons

Tags: bug, status-review, review, vote-to-reopen, reopen-dialog

In the announcement ["Review queue workflows - Final release"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/282094), where bug reports after Sept 10, 2021 are to be reported in a new question, it shows the reopen dialog in section 3 (**Leave closed reasons**):

[image: Original - Leave Closed Reason Dialog]

On our Data Science site the ["Leave Closed Reasons" dialog](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/81537) doesn't have a *next page* for the "This question doesn't meet a Data Science Stack Exchange guideline" reason:

[image: Data Science - Leave Closed Reasons dialog]

That probably results in the leave closed reason being recorded incorrectly.

This appears to affect some sites but not others, for example the [Interpersonal Skills site's dialog](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/23499) appears correctly:

[image: Interpersonal Skills - Leave Closed Reasons]

Also note, that using the same browser the dialogs on the Data Science and the Interpersonal Skills sites appear different, both in size and where they newline.

This report is about the lack of a *next page* on some sites (such as Data Science), while our Interpersonal Skills site correct advances to this next page:

[image: Interpersonal Skills - Leave Closed Reasons, page 2]

While that particular page 2 only offers a single reason some page 2's offer a few reasons; and which one is chosen affects the leave closed reason.

There is a second, different bug, which I will briefly mention here (since I don't have a screenshot, though one is probably unnecessary), and that is: Here on meta Stack Exchange the second page appears, but selecting one of the choices and submitting the close vote results in an error - the second page reasons are unusable.

Here is the promised screenshot:

[image]

That 2nd bug prevents us from choosing one of those frequently occurring reasons, and forces us to choose (usually) the first reason from the first page.

Comment: The bug in the recent edit is possibly related to a recent fix on [Question stuck in reopen queue](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16556/263137)

Comment: Potentially also related (MSO): [Reopen queue: can't choose "Leave closed" as "doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/1478931)

Comment: @KylePollard most likely. Maybe after having a bug fixed, give the developer few days where they're "assigned" to monitor possible resulting bugs? (meaning keep an eye on the meta sites, looking for related bug reports.)

Comment: @Kyle, I don't think [that comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382389/on-some-sites-the-leave-closed-reasons-dialog-is-missing-the-second-page-for?noredirect=1#comment1283171_382389) and it's associated bug are the same as #2 at the end of the question.

Comment: @V2Blast, I agree with [your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382389/on-some-sites-the-leave-closed-reasons-dialog-is-missing-the-second-page-for?noredirect=1#comment1283179_382389), bug [Reopen queue: can't choose "Leave closed" as "doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/3648282) is the same as above, except of course the dialog is different. --- The #2 bug occurred this morning, so at least that portion isn't repaired. --- I haven't checked the primary bug in this question to see if it's resolved yet. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @Rob I reviewed the fix for that bug when it went out and it included some changes to the validation on both of the pages. The original bug isn't similar, but the fix touched that code.

Comment: @Shadow We monitor for bugs after releasing, but we don't catch everything