# Can not select suitable item in the Reopen queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

I stumbled over this in the reopen queue on https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/33390644.

My intent was to choose "Leave Closed", but IMO, the close reason should be "Not a question on programming" (because the question is about using the shell history interactively).

I therefore clicked on "Leave Closed", and on "Submit". In the opening dialogue I clicked on the circle in front of "This question doesn't meet the ... guidelines". A new dialogue window opened, from which I clicked on the topmost circle, i.e. in front of "Not about programming". The circle got selected, but when I now click on the "Keep Closed" button on bottom, I get the error message "You must select a reason...", although the reason is clearly shown as selected.

I'm using Firefox 107.0.1 on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm (Firefox on macOS) - seems to be a buggy client side check, as there is no network traffic when you click 'Keep closed'.

Comment: Received "Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion" console error, when clicking on the option "This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline >"

Comment: Already reported on [Stack Overflow's Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421948/reopen-queue-cant-choose-leave-closed-as-doesnt-meet-a-stack-overflow-guid) and [again here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422020/reopen-queue-dialog-is-broken-on-second-level-shows-popup-you-must-select-a-re)

Comment: Potentially also related (here on MSE): [On some sites the "Leave Closed Reasons" dialog is missing the second page, for reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382389/335251)

Comment: [Still an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385814/278659). @V2Blast any chance of a fix for this? It seems pretty serious that we can't vote to close questions for the appropriate reason.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: The MSO post was already escalated to staff and sent to the dev team; I'll follow up with them to see if there's been any progress on this issue.

Comment: Fixed, with more details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422940/1328704).

Answer (score 6):

This appears to still be an issue. I do get the more detailed reasons when I choose "This question doesn't meet a (site name) guideline", but selecting one of those reasons does not allow me to submit it as a reason to keep the question closed. I'm on MacOS in a chromium based browser with privacy protections turned off.

As an aside, it's annoying that this dialog is different from the Close dialog. An edit can obviously change a question so that it is off-topic for any of the valid reasons a question could be closed in the first place. Why do we have a different set of reasons?

> [image: There is a "You must select a reason before submitting." error even though the dialog clearly shows a reason has been selected.]