# Anonymous user can see deleted post in Suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

If a post that has a suggested edit in review gets deleted, anyone can still see the post via the suggested edit, including anonymous users.

Is it expected behavior that anonymous users (not logged in) can see:

1. Suggested edits (or any review in queues) by link
2. Suggested edits (or any review in queues) by link, even for deleted posts

For example:

Edits for post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34110818
Link to post: [Can I get a phone number by user id via Telegram Bot API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035709/can-i-get-a-phone-number-by-user-id-via-telegram-bot-api/36639033#36639033)

[image]

---

Edits for deleted posts: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/843255
Link to post: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508266/invalid-write-of-size-8

Note: here anonymous users can even see the display names of reviewers.

[image]

UPD: seems available pages in any queue

Comment: Wait, how was that suggested edit created in the first place? AFAICT, /posts/<postId>/edit is not accessible for deleted posts unless you can already see deleted posts. And even if the user starts the edit before the post is deleted, the system doesn't allow submitting the edit if the post gets deleted before the edit is submitted (I just tested that). Perhaps it's a race condition?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, if post was deleted after edits - link to review still available. In question case for links to review in queues

Comment: Yeah yeah. I thought of that after writing the comment. I just managed to reproduce this on a post of my own.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, note, upd in end of post: seems this work not just for "Suggested edits" but for any queue

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, not yet, i'm ask about expected behavior in this cases: link to review in queues, btw duplicate without answer :)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog,  not yet, i'm ask about expected behavior in this cases: link to review in queues, btw duplicate without answer :)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, note: anonymous users can even see the display names of reviewers (on second screenshot)

Comment: New issues (such as this feedback) get a new post, thanks for this bug report.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/282094

Comment: @Rob, do you mean i should add answer with bug in post by link, or this post is enough?

Comment: Grundy, the question is sufficient. If/when it's reviewed by staff the appropriate tag will be added, later they might answer that it's fixed or simply change the tag. You could edit the question to refer to the question in my comment, or simply leave it; as staff can read deleted comments, should that occur.